# New Top Bar - "Ask Question" button disappears when I've done a search

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, top-bar

I did a search for my other question regarding the New Top Bar and found that my question hadn't been asked so thought, I'll ask the question. Wait a minute, where has the button gone:

[image]

Normally we see this:

[image]

The previous setup had the options set out like this:

[image]

Wouldn't it make sense to have the "Ask Question" button available after I've done a search like a good boy?

Comment: I had [asked for a more prominent search bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251303/make-search-more-prominent-on-the-home-page) a few years ago, and one of the things I added was a "turn this search into a question" link (which, honestly, would have just copied your search term into the "Ask Question" dialog). Maybe something like that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by @Pawel and by this screenshot, this is now complete:

[image]