# Top Navigation Update

Tags: discussion, top-bar, announcement

**Update:**
The new top navigation is now live. Please continue to post feature requests and bug reports as **new posts** and tag [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar).

---

We’ve opened up the new [Top Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/) to our power users for testing and feedback.  Big thanks for all the participation, bug reports, feature requests, and usability insights.  It was super helpful for us to uncover things we missed.

As we continue  working through bugs & tweaks, we want to keep you updated on our progress.  We’re aiming to resolve all critical bugs before launch. Some changes will require more research and testing, which we’ll treat as incremental improvements post-launch.

Please continue to post any new bugs/issues you come across by tagging [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar).

Also, keep an eye out for a blog post, [explaining in much more detail](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/), about  how and why we decided to update the navigation.

**Resolved:**

- Fixed header is now a preference [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343132/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343144/1147887), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343183/1147887), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341885/unstick-new-navigation-bar)
- Notifications colors are back [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343216/1147887), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343235/1147887)
- Dropdown hover interaction is fixed [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343136/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343180/1147887)
- Review bar is no longer covered by the top bar [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343149/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343147/new-top-nav-should-not-overlay-review-bar)
- Review icon now redirects to /review [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343135#343135), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343162/1147887)
- Added a keyboard shortcut to Help [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343167/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone)
- The Mod menu diamond and count have been decoupled [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343168/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343316/flag-count-disappears-after-closing-the-moderator-inbox)
- Stack snippets can now be closed [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343170/1147887)
- Privileges link has been added to the Achievements dropdown [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343196/1147887)
- Location suggestions on Jobs no longer overlays the header [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343212/1147887)
- Increased the clickable region of the logo [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343251/1147887)
- Keyboard shortcut issues have been resolved [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343131/1147887)
- Reputation now updates automatically [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343278/new-top-nav-reputation-change-bug)
- Visual bug in the search box is fixed [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343206/escape-to-collapse-search-and-fix-a-visual-bug-in-the-search-box)
- Toast notifications are now showing up in the correct position [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341889/pop-up-messages-shown-under-the-new-top-bar)
- Tooltips are no longer obscured by new header [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343357/1583)
- Improved drop down usability [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343180/quick-route-from-meta-to-main)
- Achievements icon doesn't highlight when there’s no badge [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343512/acheivement-icon-in-new-top-bar-is-shaded-green-even-when-theres-no-badge-achei)
- Ask A Question is now displayed on search result views [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343171/new-top-bar-ask-question-button-disappears-when-ive-done-a-search)
- Left padding issue when the browser shrinks is fixed
- Homepage link doesn’t change color on hover [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343501/1583)
- Flickering search icon on Firefox is fixed [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343532/1583)
- Header width for “unsticky” version was adjusted [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343570/1583)
- Firefox dropdown input issues were resolved [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343480/new-nav-cuts-off-the-tops-of-my-words-in-the-more-stack-exchange-communities-box), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343349#343349), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343379#343379)
- Blurry icons edge case [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343446#343446) - not reproducible

**Open:**

- Review queue  - while this redirects to /review now, we think the UX here needz moar  research and improvement. We’ll keep looking at this. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343426/should-the-review-queues-count-in-the-top-bar-show-just-suggested-edits), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343392#343392), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343342#343342), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343256#343256), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343228#343228), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343222#343222), [7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343193#343193), [8](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343190#343190), [9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343139#343139), [10](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/5516513)
- Nav Style - We're looking into adding more contrast. Any changes will require more testing because changes here could invalidate previous tests. But we promise, we are looking into this. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343106/5516513)
- Access to Help - this is currently available in the nav for anonymous & low rep users. We’re not sure it’s necessary as a persistent nav item, but we are thinking about it. [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343167/1147887), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week#comment446774_343103), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343667/5516513)

Comment: Awesome update. A lot of fixes in a very short time. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the detailed fix list and all the hard work!

Comment: Are there any plans to deploy the new top bar to all other Stack Exchange sites (when it's finalized)? Or do we have to live with an eternal inconsistency?

Comment: @Floern there are plans to at least create some consistency between the two, they may be an incremental update (given the number of custom headers there are across the network sites). They're still in early exploration, but the short answer is yes.

Comment: Why is "3" now showing up on the Featured bar and not this one??

Comment: @Des I can't see the last icon from the right when zooming in on mobile: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GA9y8.png i donno if that is a bug or ...

Comment: In general, the site does not support "zoomed" views, @Mohsen, so it might be a bug, but it's very likely "won't fix". Do you see this when you *aren't* zoomed?

Comment: @CodyGray Nope, Just when i zoom, The last two icons are not visible to click. I remember in the previous top navigation those were visible and compatible with any devices screens. (I've tested it with Safari though)

Comment: Am I imagining it, or has the background been *ever so slightly* darkened on the new top nav? It is now `#fafafb` (is that last `b` a typo?), when I would swear it used to be stark white-on-white.

Comment: @Mohsen generally fixed elements are not well supported on mobile especially when you're trying to zoom. if you really need desktop layout on your mobile, then go to your preferences and disable "sticky" nav - it should then behave better when zooming.

Comment: @CodyGray you are not imagining it - background is light grey now. it also doesn't have shadow when you're on top of the page - we add it on scroll. and last `b` is not a typo - this is one of light greys we use in SO (we have color palette we're trying to use when designing stuff)

Comment: I don't like this new banner.  Is there any way we can turn it off and go back to the good 'ol days?

Comment: Is this now live or are you still testing?  My nav just changed on me a couple minutes ago.

Comment: _"We’ve opened up the new Top Nav to our power users"_: Nitpicking: It was already available to power users, it is now enabled by default. "Open up" implies opt-in. I see no way to "Opt out".

Comment: @Paweł: Why is that `b` there? What purpose does it have? Why isn't it a nice and neat `#fafafa`? (Totally serious, these things _matter_)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - no. We are not going to maintain two designs indefinitely. Give it a few days - you can be surprised at how quickly you will get used to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver - it is now live.

Comment: @Oded OK.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Cerbrus all of the grays on Stack Overflow have a slightly cool tint. That's the reason for the 'b'.

Comment: Is it change site top navigation month or something? Github updated theirs as well...

Comment: How can I get back the normal stack overflow? I don't like this nav, it's too big and distracting.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: Are you saying there's _someone_ on the planet that can tell the difference between `#fafafa` and `#fafafb` by looking at the rendered color?

Comment: I'm not clear on the value of the "beta" flag on Documentation. Ever since gmail, I'm not sure the "beta" term has a ton of meaning to me. So is it worth having an extra element on the nav indicating this information? The importance of the "beta" label does not seem worthy of taking up space on the top real estate (pun intended) on the page.

Comment: The change just hit me literally while browsing StackOverflow so I'm still getting used to the new menu. I just wanted to add that the "old minimal black topbar" felt iconic and was a huge part of the StackOverflow identity. Kudos for working on improving StackOverflow, but I'm never forgetting my old safe-haven little black topbar ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm saying we're using LESS functions for our color variables.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: You have a very cryptic way of saying the color codes aren't hand-picked, but generated, then ;-)

Comment: @KyleBrandt "beta" means we kill it if Kevin steps out of line, *even a little bit*. It's basically a public threat.

Comment: @NickCraver But my assertion is that Kevin is resigned to his destiny of being sacrificed without the need to indicate it on the top nav.

Comment: @Des It really disaster. Now I forced to use Tampermonkey or UBlock to remove it. Fixed-positioned elements is distraction! When we read and write code and prose, we want to think about code and prose. We don't need see our badges and login options permanently.

Comment: @johnc.j. - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: Is there any quick way to switch between SO and Meta?  I expected the logo in the opt left to open a la old site, but I don't see any way to switch back and forth.

Comment: looks awasome :) well done guys

Comment: No, I can't look the screen closer..

Comment: @PatrickHaugh site switcher is now in right corner (that hamburger-ish icon). we gonna update that across Stack Exchange at some point too

Comment: I loved this new topbar :):)

Comment: I don't understand what problems does this oversized top bar solve.

Comment: I don't particularly dislike the new theme but I spend my time on 3 SE sites regularly. It's very annoying to switch between the two layouts. Wonder if I can stick to the old one until the change is rolled out to all SE networks so that I can get some sense of consistency? From what I have seen on meta so far, I think the answer is no?

Comment: I dig it! It's shiny!

Comment: Sooo pretty.. Love the minimalism. Less evidently is more!

Comment: @Pogrindis: minimalism? The new bar is twice the size of the old one.

Comment: @Cerbrus new header is combination of navigation and topbar (that dark bar) and by saying "old one" you're talking only about the latter. but new header is smaller than old nav AND topbar combined.

Comment: Old one was better. But this is open to criticism since it is new. Of course people will get used to it. Again, please revert to the old one.

Comment: @Cerbrus who said size is minimalism ? Less clutter is minimalism.. And less contrast, more streamlined.. Less focus pointed to navbar.. So yes, minimalist.

Comment: I prefer it and particularly enjoy the extending search bar. I wonder whether it should be a touch thinner though...

Comment: If you liked the old design more, here's my CSS to make the bar thinner, disable the search animation and rearrange some buttons, amongst other things. A sort of pro-bar if you will, moving the inbox and such to the top left for easier access. [**CSS for a thinner and rearranged top nav bar.**](https://georgegarside.com/blog/stack-exchange/better-top-nav-stack-overflow/) It's closer to the original design, but wasn't created solely for that purpose. It keeps most of the new design elements.

Comment: Am I the only one that see this and thinks: Hey, this looks like a loading bar!

Comment: @Pogrindis those are very subjective... I don't like the bar being twice the size it needs to be. There's no practical reason for it being that high.

Comment: Should be more thinner! and what if it goes black again ;)

Comment: Loved it, Perfect UX now :-)

Comment: You have to wonder why a (sticky when scrolled) "Back to top" button wasn't added at the same time, unless nobody made a feature request for it. Besides that, yeah I like the new (sticky) header. (Or should I have I added this in an answer as a feature request)? or am I just too lazy to hit the "Home" button on my keyboard? *lol* but that would take my hand away from my coffee cup.

Comment: looks so nice. I loved it.

Comment: This was brilliant timing after the Github navbar messup. This new header looks so much better, I'm glad it's dark text on a lighter background. Nicely done!

Comment: Oh My Deity -- I *HATE* the new top nav bar!!! CHANGE IS BAD! It looks so weird and you're fixing something that wasn't broken. I hate it so much. Can you give an option to use the good version if we aren't up for this? I know, I know, most comments are positive and I'm sure the UX guys know what's best, but maybe I'm not ready for it.

Comment: Any support for older browsers? It's awesome that you are moving forward, but if you don't want people to use your site, having it broken in older browsers is definitely a way to do that. For my current testing browser, the navigation doesn't flow left to right, but top to bottom, and covers up 430px of the top of the page. I changed it so it is no longer fixed positioning (in the settings), but it still covers some of the top content.

Comment: @JoshH - we are looking into that.

Comment: I gotta say, nice work. Love it. The new floating option was the difference between "what have you done" and "not bad, not bad at all". This is awesome, and sort of goes back to SO's roots as far as top bar + site color scheme matching goes. Really glad to see the current scheme finally put out of its [misery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207796/is-the-meta-top-bar-resembling-googles-design-distinctive-enough/207806#207806). Sure it could use a few tweaks but really great direction.

Comment: Can you provide us with a couple of skins to choose from. I liked the black header... I don't like the light-gray header on white background.

Comment: Why do you people have to keep changing things that aren't broken? This is a Q&A site, not some web brogrammer muscle-flexing exposition.

Comment: I hate the new nav bar. I dunno if I'm just not used to it or if its actually bad. I kinda liked having my new notifications inbox not tucked away in the far right corner where I never look. It used to be the first thing to catch my eye. Also, meta is now harder to get to. The help menu seems to have disappeared. If your fixing the top bar meta should have been made easier to get to (clicking on the help menu was never intuitive for me, and a button to get to chat should have been added). I also seriously hope you fixed the terrible search before making it so prominent.

Comment: I love the new nav bar - great work, guys and gals! :)

Comment: @helrich, I agree with you.  I very much dislike the new NavBar, I missed the old black bar immediately.  Designers:  Why were we NOT polled as a community before this change went into effect?

Comment: @T-Heron because [only 88,000 clicks daily](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1) on the old nav-bar apparently, wasn't being used enough. Plus they thought people should be clicking on Jobs and Documentation more...not me. Just like the majority of people don't use the site properly but "hey let's pander to them anyway!".

Comment: I'm downvoting this question to show my discontent with the new nav. I encourage others who are also discontent to do the same.

Comment: If it's not BROKEN don't FIX IT.... I'm glad some people have the time to *"hypothesize[d] that a lack of engagement with the nav was due to a combination of browsing habits, ..."*, the problem is these designers with excess time on their hands usually get it wrong... Switching the inbox, points, etc. to the far-right of the bar is a **visual train-wreck**. While in the grand scheme of things, it doesn't really matter, this "let's dork with something that is working well for reasons we just dreamed up and that make sense to me" has been the downfall for some pretty good user interfaces.

Comment: Designers' war on contrast continues. So tired of this minimalist fad.

Comment: Question? - If you are not now excluding clicks on the ***StackOverflow.com*** icon/link moved to the oversized bar, won't that invalidate any comparison between clicks on the old nav bar and clicks on this new behemoth? Since there must be some way of measuring "*engagement*" (whatever that actually means), if the clicks on the new bar now exceed clicks on the old, but it is due largely to refreshes of the question list that was not in the bar originally -- how does that help?

Comment: Sorry but it's pretty awful. Not much else to say about it. Just bad.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin We tracked everything that was in the old (topbar and nav) and new (consolidated topbar and nav) and compared the results from each link in both versions.

Comment: @Paweł That's it thanks. 'Disable stickyness' worked✌️

Comment: The new top nav is not much satisfying. White white looks weird.

Comment: I like this design, it's compact and looks pleasant to eyes.

Comment: I would prefer I can hide the top bar, since my screen high is not so bigger, this kind of bigger top bar cover the visible area of this site.

Comment: Congrats, it's so ugly I don't even want to return to SO any more unless I badly need to.

Comment: For those agree with me, that the old one looked better, feel free to make your voice heard in [Can we have the old nav back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343868/can-we-have-the-old-nav-back) post

Comment: You had a look. Now you don't. so sad! (I just wanted to say so in the blog, but can't without bowing to faceshit, twister or grogl. Being a SO user is just not good enough, it seems.. Extra sad!!) - Will we get used to it?? Both of my knees hurt. For years now. I got used to it. They still hurt.

Comment: _"I got used to it. They still hurt."_ I need to remember that one, @TaW! I never liked the _"You'll get used to it."_ "defense".

Comment: @Martin: _the "old minimal black topbar" felt iconic and was a huge part of the StackOverflow identity._ My sentiments __exactly__!

Comment: That's fine– be happy you won't have to deal with it every day like we will the poorly designed nav bar.

Comment: Normally I click on my notifications as soon as arrive on SO. This time it took me reading four different posts before I spotted them. I think an important metric to compare would be the amount of time before a user acknowledges there notifications. I think it has increased. Someone else pointed out [in a comment on the blog post](http://disq.us/p/1g774xe) that the appearance of the green you-got-rep  notification is less exciting. Thats bad. A large portion of your content exists just because someone was looking for that good feeling you get when you see it. It is an addiction.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms this is something we'll be carefully monitoring over the next month. Right now there is an increase in acknowledgements of the rep notifications in the new version, but we want to make sure that's not just because of the novelty of the design update and that the increase sustains over time.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I'm not saying it will decrease the actually clicks, it will increase the amount of time before those statuses are noticed and addressed. I read three posts on SO before noticing your ping in my inbox. Usually I see it the first time.

Comment: My god, how do you log out now without having to read 45,000 pages ???

Comment: @GiantCowFilms the metric I was looking at was the number of notification dropdowns shown. I'm sure there's a certain amount of discomfort from muscle memory for regular contributors who are used to seeing their reputation in the old location. We hope that will resolve with time, but to be sure, we are tracking this.

Comment: @sln the location of logout in the site switcher being awkward is something that came up in every usability test. We have plans to update this in the future. I agree, it's not located in the most intuitive location right now.

Comment: I should have realized it was the site switcher, thanks!

Comment: @sln in both the new and old, all participants had a difficult time finding this. The most expected location was under the avatar.

Comment: I like that it floats, but it's obnoxiously huge, and the low contrast is painful to look at.

Comment: The float should be anchored to the right, not the left, as the RHS is the useful part of the bar. Obviously no-one has ever tested this on an iPad: when you zoom in a bit to make it readable, all the buttons on the right float off the screen.

Comment: Can we please have an option to revert to the previous design? I don’t even find/see the indicators of having new messages or karma any more (and when I look into that corner where they now are, which is so far right that it’s usually off-screen and requires horizontal scrolling anyway), the large number of review tasks overshadows it and confuses me.

Comment: I'm wondering where the links went to get the ["Help" section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to grab some links as to the "What to ask/how to ask/what not to ask"....  for bad questions. Where did that go and how to find it? Or am I just blind? Edit: The only place I can see where it is, is at the bottom of the pages; why just there? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was brought up before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343167/534109 - seems intentional.

Comment: @TiesonT. I did see that and this post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343165/1415724 - Personally, I liked having the Help section available at a mouse-reach, rather than going to the bottom of the page. I think there are mixed reviews as to who likes what. Sort of like "I don't like beans, but I'll eat it if it's chili", but "my Mikey will eat anything" ;-) so, they decided what's "good for us" (for us).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I liked having the Help link available as well - it was a lot easier to copy/paste the relevant URL into a comment on questions that needed it.

Comment: @Tieson T My thoughts exactly. There are a lot of questions that need to be nudged in order for OP's to go through the "Help" section and read up on how to ask a good question, what to ask/not to ask, etc. We see this day in and day out. I feel it would only make perfect sense for them to simply just add a mere `href` for [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and wouldn't take up so more room really; it's not as if they don't "have" room in the navbar or the dropdown hamburger.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343959/include-the-help-link-in-the-source-of-the-navbar - yes?

Comment: @TiesonT.  Totally.

Comment: This is much better. The old header did not really work with **white-on-black** windows/firefox settings: It showed the entries as black-on-black so i had to guess where to click. I think it is because the old one was only icons with onClick handlers and the new one has anchor-tags. This might also make it better for **blind people**'s page readers

Comment: Header look like normally,It's not look like stackoverflow standard.

Comment: I want my old lovely black topbar back

Comment: Can we have the old one back? This does not look professional at all.

Comment: Initially, I didn't like the design, but now that we are two days in, I am already use to it and I forget the old design (however, the review notification needs to go). I remember all the outrage when the topbar was changed to black a couple years ago... people just need time to adapt.

Comment: I still scroll down to get rid of it ... - well,  habits. Can't you make it a bit thiner?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to (drastically) change the look of what was already the signature part of the site. The new toolbar is not bad in general but the old one was just better. Its darker theme gave a really nice contrast against the rest of the site and the site logo. It was already a cool toolbar. I could look at someone's computer screen from like 5 meters away and easily realize it's SO. This one just doesn't have the same identity.

Comment: The new navbar is fine.  Just make it NOT sticky.  There is no need for it.

Comment: @heez - You can disable the stickiness. On your profile page, go to "Edit Profile & Settings" > "Preferences" > "Disable stickiness"

Comment: Hmm... `#dddddd` _appears_ to provide a decent level of contrast, without being overly intrusive; I believe it's the shade used in Steven Penny's theme, but I'm not sure.  It doesn't appear to conflict with anything other than the "Beta" notice for Documentation, as far as I can tell right at the moment; I don't have mod tools, nor do I have any rep gains at the moment, so I can't be 100% certain.  Looks like it could be a decent starting point for testing, maybe.  Nothing unbearable at the moment, though, so this should probably wait until any bugfixes are done.

Comment: @JustinTime - A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away `#eee` (which is *very* similar to the color of this code block) was the original topbar color. I still use it. It has a contrast ratio of 1.16:1 (4 times that of the current fafafb color).

Comment: Where is the help button?

Comment: @UweBlock http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343167#343167 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone

Comment: For all the "what problem was this fixing?" or "it wasn't broken, don't fix it" types - @KurtisBeavers did post on the blog, in detail, exactly why it was an issue and why it needed fixing. https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/

Comment: Did you guys try zooming the screen? the new bar takes almost 1/3 of screen height. This happens in both desktop and mobile. in previous layout I just could scroll and it was out of way, but now there is no way to do that. the option in pref page is only available if you are logged in. I think it is better to have it fixed as default.

Comment: where is documentation link gone?

Comment: the one that confuses me is that I get different tabs if i click on the stackoverflow icon vs clicking on 'questions'. It took me a long time to work out why 'interesting' kept disappearing

Comment: I don't mind the new nav bar at all. It took a bit of getting used to when it first showed up as I had to examine all of the icons and discover what they did which then led me to how you switch between sites. However, it will be much better when it exists on all the sites as the context switching throws me. It is just disconcerting to go to the right side to switch between the sites and then once you're there suddenly have to go back to the left side to get back.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't like the new layout. I've got the better part of a decade of muscle memory telling me for where to check for notifications, and you've broken that for _documentation_ of all things - the one part of the site that I avoid like the plague. To make it worse, yo've moved the numbers I actually care about into a clutter of other numbers, making everything harder to identify. Time to write another userscript to get rid of the nonsense I don't want. You make a lot of excellent changes but sometimes you really drop the ball. IMO this is a case of the latter.

Comment: Any way to get dark(black) theme back?

Comment: Please DON'T roll this out across the other sites.  :glumface:

Comment: Where is the Help Center in the new SO navbar? The only place I see a 'help' link is at the bottom of the page. <actually reads whole post> Ok, found that last bullet in the question, so it's apparently vamoosed in my pageview since I'm not low-rep. PUT IT BACK UP THERE. I'm at 8.5k rep on Chem.SE, and I still click over to the help center somewhat regularly -- likely will want to even more so on SO.

Comment: Is there any plans to implement this on the chat site too? It's very confusing at the moment switching back and forth between chat and SO with the two different nav bars

Comment: -1 for not being a question.

Answer (score 304):

The new top nav [needs a dark theme](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343106). Since the design/moderation team
has gone through with the white/white theme, all I can do is to help people
get the dark theme back. To that end, you can use the
[Stylish add-on](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) with [Dimitri’s dark theme](//gist.github.com/g00glen00b/328bba7fdb392d3b8a7f2e6f7d468dbc):

> [image: alpha]

Or [my dark theme](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/c790d2a714be859c7763ef581038c155693409e6/stylish/stackoverflow.css) with [reduced height](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341892):

> [image: bravo]

Comment: Under Open: "We're looking into adding more contrast. Any changes will require more testing because changes here could invalidate previous tests. But we promise, we are looking into this."

Comment: I'll repost my version too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIx8L.png - Light gray, no shadow, no orange line - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kobi/ff7188a93e1111745c8e06ede363df97/raw/Stack%2520Overflow%2520Navigation%2520Bar%2520-%2520Light.css

Comment: I disagree - the nav bar did need some kind of contrast, but not a dark colour necessarily. FWIW I think the light gray adds a nice touch of contrast without making the whole thing "in your face"

Comment: _I think the light gray adds a nice touch of contrast_ Huh? Contrast??? Really? Not in a long stretch should 'light gray' (which is more 'ghost white' btw) and 'contrast' be in the same sentence!

Comment: I think what @MacroMan meant by contrast was that it stands apart from the rest of the site content as a distinctly different area.

Comment: @Kurtis: Yeah, well but IT DOESN'T. In fact it is even a tad brighter than the Firefox bars! A good UI will always make it clear where the frame ends and where the content starts. It tries to do that with that weird orange line; "so sad".

Comment: I think the whole thing is very subjective, so we will have to agree to disagree

Comment: Aw, I just changed my profile pic to match the old reputation icon when it's green. Now I have to earn reputation and crank up paint.net again. =(

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga Invalidating previous tests is not a problem if the previous tests said that no contrast was fine, tbh

Comment: @TylerH I think that quote's worded awkwardly, and a better way to put it might be to say "Any major changes will require validation that they perform as well as the tested version."

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Right, I understand you don't want regressions. I was just pointing out cheekily that while white on white is a stark and clean look, it's a bit strenuous on the eyes.

Comment: The shadow makes you keep looking at the top nav every couple seconds. It's too obvious and distracting, even with the sticky disabled.

Comment: I just logged in today and see the new white nav bar. Quite blinded by the light. Yes I couldn't agree more it needs a dark bar.

Comment: i have an even darker stylish-template that also works flawlessly with the new topbar. btw i noticed it just changed back to solid. good one.

Comment: Looks like it has some contrast now and is not pure white. #fafafb

Comment: 1.04:1 is the contrast ratio for fafafb to fffff... might as well be white.

Comment: Seriously, you have to disclose your affiliation. I don't want to lock this, but I absolutely will if you insist.

Comment: Seriously, Steven? Even after @Undo locks your post to stop you from rolling back, you wait for the unlock and roll back anyway - without even bothering to justify yourself in the comments? Whether the edit the mods are insisting on here is reasonable or not - and there's perhaps a case to be made that it's sufficiently clear that you are the author without that edit - it's common sense that if you're going to repeatedly defy the men with the big sticks, you should at least *try* to persuade them or others that you're right to do so.

Comment: There should be "Steven's dark theme". I don't know that guy "my"!

Comment: Also, remove the _fixed class from the navbar to make it move with the rest of the page, like it should.

Comment: @brzuchal *"Steven's dark theme", authored by me.*

Comment: The link to Steven's the dark theme looks like it is broken.  Should we edit the whole thing out if that was removed?

Comment: Look how it looks with my Stylish dark theme (it sucks): http://imgur.com/JaUG76r

Answer (score 198):

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The review icon is problematic.

- It has a notification number which can never be dismissed. This is painful to constantly see. It is so distracting that I removed the entire icon with a userscript.
- It is a link in a group of dropdowns. This makes it likely to waste time from users aiming at the dropdowns.
- As an icon which represents only one link, it wastes important space, which could be used by other tools.

Make the review icon a dropdown. Remove its floating count. Have the dropdown contain links to:

- review (only for 500+)
- tools (only for 10k+)
- tour
- help center

Comment: From the question: "Open: Review queue - while this redirects to /review now, we think the UX here needz moar research and improvement. We’ll keep looking at this.". We are painfully aware that it isn't doing a good job - mostly due to its history - give us some time to figure things out.

Comment: I disagree with the removal of the review count number. But if it's going to be removed, they'll have to change the icon itself, because it looks like a notification/message/chat icon. On meta (which rarely has a review count) I always mistake the icon for the inbox.

Comment: @Oded - That is fair. I just wanted to reiterate the point here. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @yellowantphil: I think you mean less than 3000 rep. The suggested edit queue on Meta is open to 2kers, but only ever shows anything to 5kers, as there are no suggested edits on child metas except for tag wikis.

Comment: I was under the impression you could review first and late posts at 500 rep from this privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues so that is where the 500 rep suggestion came from.

Comment: I noticed a significant increase in review activity, which I think is definitely related to the new review icon design. (Not sure if this is good or bad for the overall review quality..)

Comment: I agree with a notification number you can't dismiss being a big UX no-no.  Hope you guys are looking at that aspect as well. It's always been problematic, but it wasn't really an issue when there were 1800 pixels between it and the notifications I cared about.  **It's the proximity** that is exacerbating it.  Overall great work!

Comment: The number hanging above the review icon is easily disabled via uBlock Origin.

Comment: Upvoted for "make it a dropdown". I disagree about the task count: we sure as hell want it there, because we want people to go there and do stuff. Make the number zero!

Comment: @Raphael: Didn't Wikipedia have an epidemic of qualified authors leaving the site because editing was being shoved down their throats?  I think it's a cautionary tale...sure you want to encourage editing and moderation, but not at the expense of driving away the qualified people who are interested in donating their time to answer questions.  Not everyone who is interested in one will be interested in the other.

Comment: @MarkPeters They weren't driven away by the old navbar (which had a colorful review task count!), so I guess they won't be driven away by a little blue box now. (Also, user scripts/styles if they care *that* much.)

Comment: @Raphael: As I mentioned in my first comment, there was a major difference in the old bar because that button was right-justified, far away from your other notifications.  Your peripheral vision can easily tell when things are 10 inches away from the area you care about.  Half an inch?  Not so much.  So much harder to ignore.

Comment: "It is a link in a group of dropdowns. This makes it likely to waste time from users aiming at the dropdowns." Holy cow yes. I just misclicked on it twice while trying out the site switcher. That's a nasty little UX bite: navigating away when all I wanted was to open a menu.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird that four icons right next to each other result in three dropdowns and one hard page navigation...

Comment: @Raphael I've given the whole review button `display: none !important` with Stylish for exactly the reason MarkPeters describes (and not just on the number because of it going to a whole new page instead of being a dropdown)

Comment: Agree 1000% the review count is visually distracting.  We need an option to completely disable displaying the review icon, for those of us who have given up on participating in review queues.  If you want to reduce the sizes of the review queues make it harder to post crap to begin with.

Comment: [How can I hide review notifications?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343816/395857)

Comment: I guess those who like to review like to have a button there although I always found the displayed number to be quite arbitrary and not useful to me. Those who don't want to review right now can just hide the notification relatively easy, although an option somewhere would be better and not showing the numbers which are not helpful anyway would be simply the best. I turned the whole button off just now, so I don't care much.

Comment: I've never had a notification icon: I'm low rep (500 < rep < 2k); Don't have any review related badges; rarely review items. Perhaps there's a trigger for it.

Comment: This is done-ish: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Comment: @Shog9 - Looks good. No room for the help link I suppose? At least I can userscript one in there :D

Comment: We talked about that, but I'm not a big fan of grab-bag "overflow" menus, @travis; had enough of that crap in various mobile apps.

Comment: @Shog9 - It does look busy, even with every queue. Perhaps it would have been worthwhile to have just had the top 3 queues listed, as in order by count, take 3, and display those results; and then you would have the all queues link, as well as perhaps a help link? I just feel like people reviewing need access to help, they post here all the time about their "review ban yyy??? all i did wuz accept plagiarism" type of stuff. If users are going to be reviewing, they should at least be able to know what behavior or patterns they are supposed to support or oppose.

Comment: That would give you a menu whose options changed, seemingly at random @travis. Swap endless meta posts about the count for endless meta posts about the schizo menu. Most queues have help *in them* (not that it gets read).

Comment: At least meta posts about the schizo menu would be amusing to see the random tangential actions people associate with what they had done to make the order change ;)

Answer (score 169):

The thin colored border along the top is suggestive of a loading bar and feels out of place to me.  I think it would look better left out.

Comment: yep. like an angular-ish progress bar. But I can definitely live with it, it's not blue and does not move, so...

Comment: I never saw that on meta (grey bar), but with the orange on Stack Overflow I can't unsee it now - good point.

Comment: Same impression.

Comment: Doesn't bother me - adds small detail which I find quite attractive

Comment: Same here. Feel agony that something is still loading...

Comment: Its like the page has completed loading, but not finished yet somehow. Waits for page to complete loading :)

Comment: Wipe that out.My eyes on that orange bar grrrr who add this -_-

Comment: I didn't notice it in the context of a loading bar, but I do think it makes the whole bar look top-heavy.  I think it would be better either gone or at least diminished to be symmetric with the thin gray bar at the bottom.

Comment: Agreed -- I think it's particularly out of place due to the abundance of all the other horizontal orange lines you can already see, as evident [in this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/23moI2s.png). Plus the oranges aren't all the same orange, which throws me off.

Comment: Please remove the orange line - or make it configurable as well - like the stick nav

Comment: Then I guess the site is always [puts on sun glasses] Fully loaded. YAAAAAAAOW

Comment: I'm guessing that they added the orange top border so it draws your attention upwards. But that's super annoying if I'm trying to concentrate on the actual content of the site. It's harder to read questions and answers if the big orange border in my peripheral vision keeps nagging me to look up. Removing that border makes all the difference in the world: http://i.imgur.com/cGTEUsU.png

Comment: So much this! The orange bar reminds me far too much of YouTube’s red loading bar, so I just keep thinking the page isn’t loaded yet. It’s not even that I need to look at the bar, I just realize it’s there and have this uneasy feeling.

Comment: Frankly it looks like a copy of what LinkedIn have done (their's is a progress bar) - which makes this more confusing..

Comment: From the bar, I always get the feeling that I'm not at the top of the page, but further down, and there is space to scroll up... And then there isn't. I find it very unsettling.

Comment: Yes! Please remove the coloured bar! It feels like you have drawn on my browser, and makes things feel very inconsistent when flicking between sites (non SE sites)

Comment: If you use uBlock Origin, the following filter will get rid of it: `stackoverflow.com##header.so-header:style(border-top: 0px #000000)`

Comment: I could almost understand the orange line if it were placed below the navbar as a separator, but what is its purpose sitting there at the top of the page? It's so bright and distracting for no reason.

Comment: I came to this post for the same reason. That orange colored line is very annoying. Just what's the point of it?

Answer (score 110):

I dislike some key aspects of it:

- It's much too tall in my opinion.
- Not enough contrast. Maybe it would bother me less with the dark scheme, but the not-so-dark gray of some of the content vs the light gray is not enough. Or the grayish orange (of the bronze badges).
- The "Questions" section is highlighted - as I write this reply - with an underline, even though I'm not looking at a list of questions (actually, this underline is generally annoying when there isn't some open pane directly under it).
- The dark colorscheme from before is much more to my liking.

End result: It's distracting and makes me kind of edgy. Please consider reverting it.

Comment: Agreed, a height of even 50px instead of 57px, with a 1px top-border, would be a large improvement.

Comment: The height isn't really much of an issue once you turn on the "Disable fixed site navigation" setting in your user preferences.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Umm, it's also less of an issue when I'm not using my computer... more seriously, though, it's too tall whether you can scroll away from it or whether you can't. It's visually disturbing. I didn't complain about lack of screen real estate for other content, it's just too tall.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion I guess. Keep in mind though that the total size of the header is actually _smaller_ than it used to be. The logo and nav buttons used to be below the old bar, and they took up a _lot_ more space in that position. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea5NY.png I'm really suprised people are complaining about the new nav being too big even though it's _smaller_ than it used to be.

Comment: @Ajedi32: The navigation bar and the header are two different things. Looking at the images, I'd say my discomfort is with how the new bar sort of "sticks the header into the navbar".

Comment: @einpoklum Not anymore they're not. Personally I find the size of the new bar to be just fine. It's very much in line with many other sites I use regularly like GitHub, GitLab, Gmail, etc. Like I said though, everyone's entitled to their opinion.

Comment: @Ajedi32: (1) It's larger than GitHub's (2) GitHub's is also on the large side (3) In GitHub, you can mostly ignore the bar other than for searching (notifications are not that significant AFAIAK), but here you use it a whole lot. (4) GitHub's bar doesn't feel bloated, while SO's does. I can't put my finger on it exactly, it's just that you overdid it any they didn't.

Comment: This new nav bar is just awful, no contrast, too tall, the placement of the Inbox doesn't match up with the rest of the StackExchange sites, and most importantly, if something isn't broke, why was it "fixed"?  A down-vote belongs to the brainiac designers who came up with this hot mess.

Comment: The bar "feels right" when it is at the top of a page - it seems they designed it solely looking at that. When you start scrolling down the size just feels out of place and wacky. I think as most modern pages do nowadays the bar should reduce in size a bit when you don't look at the top of the page (or if that's too much effort: just make it always smaller).

Comment: @paul23: Disagree. It should be shorter everywhere and not grow and shrink.

Answer (score 90):

Assuming this will eventually be rolled out to the broader network:

> Access to Help - this is currently available in the nav for anonymous & low rep users. We’re not sure it’s necessary as a persistent nav item, but we are thinking about it.

As a moderator, I use the help menu often when assessing requests to migrate something to another site. It's good to have a reasonably fast way to get to `/help/on-topic` without typing it out manually.

Comment: Select a random post in the site and type `[help/on-topic]` :P

Comment: We did add a keyboard shortcut - G -> E will navigate to the help center.

Comment: That's probably good enough for me, @Oded, although it still makes it a bit more difficult on a tablet. I can't stand moderating on a tablet anyway, but I know some others do.

Comment: @Undo - current state of affairs is not set in stone. There are a few good use cases for having help more easily available to higher rep users - it is a matter of figuring out where to put it.

Comment: @Oded Any reason it couldn't live in the site picker? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz5qq.png Seems like a logical place to put it and not too messy/crowded.

Comment: I think this has been now rolled out to broader network as It just changed my nav to this update even though I never signed up for the trial.

Comment: Scenario. Arrogant veteran user responding with comment to inane newbie user: "This question is not very good, did you even read the site help?" Inane newbie: "Nope! I didn't know there was one. Where can I find it?" Arrogant veteran: "Umm... it used to be up there to the right... umm... ask on meta." Inane newbie: "What is a meta and where can I find one!" Arrogant veteran: "Umm... it used to be up there to the left... err..." Inane newbie: "I don't get it. Code plz! Now!"

Comment: What @Lundin said, but `s/arrogant/helpful/g`.

Comment: @Oded Wow, `G` followed by `E` to go to the help center...that's so obvious and discoverable! And easy to remember! Because `G` is...ummm....the first letter in "Ghostbusters"...and `E` is the second letter of "Help". There's **absolutely no way** that a new user won't automatically know that this keyboard shortcut exists. Well done!

Comment: @JackM See the question - a link is supposedly available for anon and low rep folks (I haven't confirmed that). The shortcut is enough for my power user needs.

Comment: @JackManey - what do you suggest? H was already taken by Homepage. If you have the keyboard shortcuts enabled, the ? shortcuts show you a menu leading you to the different ones - it is discoverable. It is possible we are all idiots at Stack Overflow - it is also possible we are not.

Comment: @Oded I know this sounds a bit old-fashioned, but I'd suggest a link that is either in the sidebar or navbar and is consistently placed for every single user, regardless of rep level or whether they're logged in.

Comment: @Oded Oh, and incidentally, pressing `?` has no discernable effect.

Comment: @JackManey - sure, if you don't have the keyboard shortcuts enabled, they don't work.

Comment: As we stated elsewhere - we are still looking at things, including the help link. Takes time.

Comment: @Oded Lemme guess: new users will have to manually fiddle-fart around in their settings to enable keyboard shortcuts so that they can get the shortcut to get at the help page that used to be displayed prominently... Is that right? If so, do you *honestly* not see a problem with that?

Comment: @JackManey - anonymous users as well as new users (without access to review queues) don't have a review link - they have (shock horror) a help link.

Comment: @Oded - Yes, because non-new users would have no reason to go to the help page whatsoever without typing `:wq` or `gh` or whatever it is to get there instead.

Comment: @JackManey - you seem to ignore - we **are looking at it**. Things do not happen immediately. I guess that's not good enough for you.

Comment: @Oded How did this get through user testing? Did no one bring this up at all before rolling out the new navbar? I find that a bit hard to believe.

Answer (score 78):

I see two flaws that should be addressed.

---

The current inbox icon is the only skeuomorphic element in the UI, the rest is nice and flat. Because of its shape, the icon forces an unnecessary 3d look to the entire bar. The inbox icon should be changed to a flat 2d look, so it is consistent with other icons. This is a good time to fix it. For example:

[image]

---

The other is the height of the new navigation bar. Since the posts are restricted by width, and scrolling is required, the usable screen height is a valuable resource and should not be wasted. I think there are a few pixels that could be shed away from it:

[image]

Comment: I agree with screen real estate being at a premium, especially on laptops. I raised this same issue - so we added a preference. You can disable the sticky behavior completely in your settings: http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current - it's called **Disable fixed site navigation**.

Comment: _"the usable screen height is a valuable resource and should not be wasted"_: You might want to crop that 2nd image a little ;-) @NickCraver: This one isn't about the bar being sticky. It'a about the bar going on a diet. It's fat.

Comment: @NickCraver Actually my answer is about the whitespace in the bar itself, not its behavior. I think that the 'sticky' behavior is a good optional feature.

Comment: FWIW I agree, I hope we slim it down a little, especially given it's sticky by default. That being said, it is far less overall height at the top of the page than there was before. It was about 146px before site content (see http://serverfault.com), now it's about 80px. So make sure you're comparing apples to apples on usable space. Still a step up...but yeah I wouldn't complain if it was a bit thinner than current.

Comment: Not to mention the current notification icon is a dead-tree physical box, which, let's be honest, most people don't recognize these days. An envelope would be much more obvious for "notifications/messages" as that's the standard 'mail' icon.

Comment: @NickCraver I'd love to see it slimmed down to 1px top border and 50px header height :-)

Comment: I agree about the height of the bar - thanks for making the stickiness optional, but even then I think it feels too fat.  However, I may be one of a minority of folks that actually likes the paper tray icon.  Makes me feel nostalgic :).

Comment: @Ajean I wasn't arguing against the object in the icon, but how it is represented. I can be a tray, as long as it is 2d.

Comment: @NickCraver As I explained [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343174#comment445915_343174) making the bar unsticky doesn't solve the issue of it being too tall. I like the sticky bar and don't mind it taking up space if I think it has a purpose, yet I still don't want unnecessary space used. I created a userscript to change the height to 40px and `.so-header .my-profile { padding:13px 10px; }` and it still looks good. I also made the search bar a few pixels shorter.

Comment: @TotZam I didn't claim it does, but it is actually smaller both initially and still 0 when scroll initially. It's just *aesthetically* an issue if it conflicts with your preferences. I'm lobbying to get it slimmed down a bit internally as well - don't worry, I like my screen space too :)

Comment: FWIW, once you "Disable fixed site navigation" the amount of space taken up by the header on SO is actually significantly _less_ than it used to be. Compare the old nav: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea5NY.png with the new one. There's no SO logo on the page anymore, and the nav buttons have been moved to the bar.

Comment: +1 for adding the word 'skeuomorphic' to my (non-native speaker's) mental dictionary. I concur to reduce the height of the bar by eliminating the superficial vertical whitespace. The overall vertical space need (bar + title section) has been reduced but why not going all the way ? Given today's prevalent screen dimensions you need all the vertical space you can get unless functionality is compromised. There is a subjective aspect to the latter, but the whitespace appears to be of aesthetic value only - anyone disagreeing pls supply hard evidence aka papers.

Answer (score 58):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

This is somewhat of an addendum to [Travis' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/2756409).

#### Please change the review icon.

Right now it is a speech bubble with what looks like a writing utensil either on a flat surface or next to an eraser. A speech bubble is almost universally used on the internet for chat messages, but we have a 3D physical desk-top inbox for letters as our notifications/messages icon (there's already an answer addressing that).

Now that I know it's the review icon, I know what you're going for, but there are a ton of better (read: more obvious) icons out there to draw inspiration from that connote "review" more clearly than a speech bubble with a pencil. Even changing the speech bubble background to a document icon would be a big improvement.

Comment: I'll second this - I had zero idea what the review icon was for until I hovered for the tooltip.

Comment: Thankfully, uBlock Origin can make short work of the annoying number hovering on top of the review icon.

Comment: I mean.... you can't really see the review icon due to it always being covered by 3-4 numbers anyway

Comment: @KevinB There's almost never a number on Meta, and the issue if seeing numbers on it compounds with the issue of it looking like a comment notification icon. When I logged on today and saw the new nav for the first time, I thought "WTF, I have 500+ notifications?" I may not be as confused in the future, but I'll probably still do a double take for a while, and new (or new rep-threshold) users will be confused too. It's an easily-avoidable problem by just changing the icon a bit.

Comment: @JackManey Unthankfully, that doesn't address the issue raised by my answer.

Comment: oh, cool. adblock to the rescue.

Comment: Book / Document and reading glasses is my vote.

Comment: I only knew this was the review icon because of the number sitting over it

Comment: We'll consider this. It won't be before we fix more major issues, but we'll at least consider if there's a better, more clear option. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks Kurtis. By the way, were the top bar icons crafted in-house or taken from a pre-existing pack?

Comment: @TylerH Both. We use the same pixel grid as Google material icons. All of the icons in the top bar are custom except review, which is a slightly edited version of the Google review icon. Maybe a more custom version based on this use case would be more immediately recognizable. We're planning an icon overhaul soon to utilize inline SVG's.

Answer (score 55):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Could popups please stay on top of the toolbar? I don't like how it currently can hide the top of the popup *under* the toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 47):

I think we should to inverse our brain so we can adapted with this new top bar, the right content are now in the left, why you changed the order, i think it was good?

Comment: Maybe they switched from Big Endian to Little Endian.

Comment: I actually think having stuff like that on the right is far more common than having it on the left. Most sites I know if with notification trays place that information on the right side of the screen.

Comment: I'm sad that this isn't upvoted more. Using this site for ***years***, my mind is trained to look at the top-left when I open the site. What are we supposed to get out of this? I hate this change more than I can properly articulate.

Comment: I hate that the things that I care about most (reputation change, acheivements) disappear when the screen gets narrow, and things that I care about least (Documentation, Jobs) get priority.

Comment: Ya. I came here to echo this. I also dislike having something fundamental and useful such as the network of other sites moved to the right and stuck under a generic pile of lines icon. I hate that UI convention, as to me it means "the company's design theory is that useful functions should be hidden under a generic Options icon". I hate it on Firefox, I hate it in Windows, I hate it everywhere. Just saying. But how do I _really_ feel about it? It's annoying and makes me like everything that uses it less.

Answer (score 35):

For those of us who use the site switcher (i.e. the hamburger) a lot, it's now a lot harder to do that (as it's way up on the right). More eye and mouse travel, and once you click on it more travel again (as it's left aligned, and for some reason I at least can't convince myself to click on the reputation number even though it is obvious it's the right row!).

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Any chance we could get keyboard shortcuts to make it easier to switch to the sites on our top 5 list?  Something like <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> would work, for example, or add to the <kbd>G</kbd> the <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> options.

Comment: This is a repeat of my post from the last thread - made a few minutes or so before the 3rd iteration thread was detopped in preparation for this thread...

Comment: Why does being "way up on the right" make it "a lot harder" than being "way up on the left" like it was before? I use the site switcher all the time, and my problem is just retraining my muscle memory, not that it is somehow "harder".

Comment: @NicolBolas Mouse travel.   Because most of the content is on the left, mouse travel is shorter to top left than to top right (and eye travel).  Voting buttons, questions, etc. are all on the left, so most of the time my mouse is on the left side of the screen.

Comment: One more thing about this: are all sites in StackExchange going to adopt the new layout? Or is this specific to StackOverflow? Because if this is only SO specific, then it's breaking consistency.

Comment: @giusti This request would work on all sites - there's nothing special about the new layout that would make it a problem to implement everywhere (all sites have a site switcher, it's just in different spots).

Comment: I created a tampermonkey script [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/7209/stackoverflow-questions-remap-new-nav) which will remap Questions to go to my most commonly used tab, which will do for now until/unless this gets implemented.

Comment: Yeah, the left justification of the menu items is a problem. First you go all the way right, open the menu, then you go all the way _back left_ to get to the selection you want. (Yes I know the rows trigger along their whole length, but a) that doesn't give me as good a mousing target as an icon, and b) the right end of the row is the "log out" link.) Right justification would probably look weird, though; not sure what the best answer is. Maybe left-justfy the site logos to present a target on that side...

Comment: I thought the site switcher was removed until I read this answer.

Answer (score 27):

Honestly, my first reaction was: "Oh, you hopped on the new trend of fixed "menu" bars consuming vertical screen space? Grrreat..."

And the first thing I wondered was: "How do I get this bar out of the way"?

Thanks for providing an option to let the top bar scroll up!

It's called "Disable fixed site navigation".

You have to be logged in for this to work, it's an option in your profile (click your avatar icon). Then go to the Settings tab, look for the Navigation group > Disable fixed site navigation. [Details here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343483/1600770).

I would really like this option to be available when I'm not logged in, though.

Comment: What text would you suggest for the option to make it more intuitive?

Comment: Something like "Let the top/menu bar scroll"?

Comment: Or a pair of radio buttons with labels of, eg, "Keep the navbar at the top of the screen when scrolling" and "Let the navbar disappear when scrolling down"? Almost anything other than the cryptic phrase "Disable fixed site navigation".

Comment: Where is it hidden? The default is extremely annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not technically feasible to for logged out users. Tracking the state with no reliable persistent cross-session store for tens of millions of visitors is just a crazy problem to tackle. We could do a simple drop-dead cookie, but then those add up to a *very* bloated request pipe added together.

Comment: @NickCraver I get your point, on a technical level. When I use it, however, I feel like I would be much happier with a checkbox right inside the top bar to let it scroll. I really care about vertical space when I'm reading code. I feel this need on other websites too.

Comment: @NickCraver So we will have to set it on every Stack Exchange site separately?

Comment: @VladimirF I need to talk so some people - but I plan to make that setting propagate across the network. Same for keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @NickCraver Look. I'm not a web developer or designer by either trade or profession. But even *I* know enough to know that it's quite possible to keep a navbar at the top of a page regardless of whether a user is logged in.

Comment: Maybe you just could change default setting? Fixed top bar is more than annoying :(

Comment: Maybe make it hidden when scrolled down, show when scrolled up and hide again on idle (assume that user is reading)?

Comment: Since the mid-80s when I started programming,  **vertical screen space grew by a factor of 2.7** (400 vs. 1080 pixels). In the same time, the amount of **RAM grew by a factor of 8,000** (1 MB vs. 8 GB) and the **CPU speed by perhaps 100,000** (1.4 MIPS at 16 bit vs. 100,000 MIPS at 64 bit). Screen space improvement lags behind by a whopping **3-5 orders of frigging magnitude.** If things had gone my way I'd be using my walls as monitor by now. I defend my screen space with claw and nail. And *everybody* wants the vertical space. Put the bar on the side, you are not using that space anyway.

Comment: @JackManey Of course that part is easy. I never said it wasn't. Where you store the preference for tens of millions of anonymous users (a day) is not a trivial problem to solve though. Give me a solution that scales and I'm all ears. We'd love to solve this for many reasons, but that doesn't make it an easy problem. All solutions we've seen have *major* tradeoffs.

Comment: @NickCraver Cookies.

Comment: @JackManey that doesn't work well. It doesn't work across browsers (or devices), isn't in any way related to a user, and adds quite a bit of request overhead (in bytes) times several billion requests. It also doesn't scale as you start adding things to the cookie. And you have to decode it every request. As I said: tradeoffs, *major* tradeoffs.

Comment: @NickCraver thanks for the consideration. What about a small lock icon on the top bar and an OnClick JavaScript event that changes the CSS? Sure, it's a tradeoff, it won't work across sites, but it would be available without logging in.

Comment: @Agostino but the next time you came back, it'd go back to sticky - wouldn't that be *more* infuriating?

Comment: @NickCraver Not really, I would just need to click the lock to make it go away (1 click total). Certainly faster than logging in.

Comment: Thank you.  Really, the stickiness should be turned off by default.  Sticky navbars are OK if you need them to use the website efficiently.  Unfortunately, this isn't the case for stackoverflow IMHO.

Answer (score 24):

Reading the explanation on the blog, it would appear the navigation was changed to please users who come from Google and immediately scroll down.
Reasoning was quoted from users who "do not notice anything above question title".

While I understand how removing things above the question title may have pleased such users coming from Google, what I don't understand is why said pleasing had to be at the expense of the users who use this website regularly.

I do care about what I do here, I often revisit questions I recently answered (because on many many occasions people fail to use @notifications properly), and in doing so my inbox and my rep changes icon are my main tools, along with the "all actions" tab in my profile.

Now that they are on the right, they are much less noticeable and go not only against the muscle memory but also against the natural habit of looking in the top left corner ([1](https://conversionxl.com/10-useful-findings-about-how-people-view-websites/), [2](http://gazehawk.com/blog/where-do-users-look-first/)). My most used tools are now in the zone of the least attention.

The prominent StackExchange dropdown is reduced to an icon that does not immediately tell you what it does, so Meta is now less discoverable.

The lack of the `Help` link is another inconvenience for experienced users who are willing to educate people by pointing them to certain help pages, as Help pages are now less discoverable too.

The logo before "Questions" which links to the home page does not look to be a link just like the others ("Questions", "Jobs" etc), it looks like an icon for "Questions", and because of that I have clicked "Jobs" several times already, simply because I know there must be two "question" links (https://stackoverflow.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but my mind fails to treat the logo as a separate link, and so I end up clicking the second *word* in the list which is `Jobs`. I will probably train myself to not do it eventually, but it's another example of lesser discoverability and added confusion, in my opinion.

I understand it will not be reverted, so I had to start a stylesheet that udoes most of the unwanted changes. Very much disappointed about having to do that.

On the blog you are reasoning that only 1% percent use the navbar; that may very well be true, but something tells me that the 1% of users that use the tools contributes much more than 1% of overall goodness to SO.

Comment: Why can it not be reverted? It could be...

Comment: @einpoklum http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343764/11683

Comment: They could just "consolidate" by reverting, rather than changing the other sites to the new, undesirable design.

Comment: Very important point about the eyes' "natural habit of looking in the top left corner". This re-design is very disorienting, for me. Most of the SE activity(votes, flags, edit) all take place on the left hand side of the page. Now activities are split across the page. Not very efficient for my usage.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with notifications on the left-hand side being the most efficient place. As stated in the answer, muscle memory is a big factor for users who've been using this site for years, and we understand that this change causes discomfort. At the same time, we stand by the decision to separate notifications to the right, not as an afterthought, but as a location that's a commonly used layout convention in web apps.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: The thing is, it's a combination of many discomforts in one (see my answer).

Comment: @einpoklum regarding the other points: We are planning on thinking through getting help back in as said in the OP, the Logo was a link in the previous version, and the site switcher and all of the other notifications are performing better in the new version, so that makes us believe that they're not less discoverable.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The logo was a link in the previous version, but it [contained *a word*](https://web.archive.org/web/20170126074239/http://stackoverflow.com/) (`stackoverflow`). Currently it's an icon-only logo which looks like an icon that belongs to the next *word*, "Questions".

Comment: you've been using old nav for long time so you get used to it, that's obvious. but instead of creating stylesheet to immediately revert those changes try to give new nav another week and see if you can get used to it as well.

Comment: @Paweł That's what I'm trying to do now (which is mostly because the stylesheet alone does not work because there is javascript involved that sets absolute positions on elements which cannot be overridden with a stylesheet). Obviously it's possible to get used to anything; my point is that we should not make changes that introduce discoverability/branding issues on the basis that we will eventually get used to it.

Comment: @Paweł (The branding issue is that the word "stackoverflow" now only appears in the basement. Am I on Stackoverflow? Is that a website that copies Stackoverflow on a very similar URL, showing the logo but being careful not to display the actual `stackoverflow` word? I cannot tell. You would need to have *previous experience* to comprehend the new look properly, which kind of goes against the stated goal of pleasing *new users*.)

Comment: @GSerg: "*The branding issue is that the word "stackoverflow" now only appears in the basement.*" That's more the fault of "Documentation"; If that weren't there, then there'd be room for the full title of the website. Yet another reason to ditch that garbage.

Comment: The redesign combines an unwanted shift of notifications to the far-right side along with what looks like a chat-bubble-icon for review counts. That's *incredibly* distracting. I've tried liking the new header, in good faith, but dang it, I just don't. I don't like the loss of SO's previously unique graphic demarcation. I don't like the absence of contrast, nor the push to make the site monetization aspects more prevalent. And I also realize I'm just a dog whose owner has decided to repaint the food dish.

Comment: Let's just call the new Nav Bar for what it is - a hot mess of a change foisted upon us by a small minority of people in charge who thought they were doing it for the "better good".   I've given it two weeks - and I still think the execution of this change by those "in charge", like the the new bar itself, was poorly done.

Answer (score 18):

The bar is too big on smaller resolution screen (1366x768). Please either fold it when scrolling up/down (and unfold it when hovered) or make it smaller.

Also, consider moving it to the side if the resolution allows it (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/why-do-many-sites-leave-half-of-each-webpage-empty). That'd be a nice usage of the empty space. (Don't clog the side, though, just like said in the link as well!)

Comment: You can un-stick it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: Oh, nice. Thanks. This is so much better (in my opinion).

Comment: It's great that there's an option, but is it really a good idea to have the bar sticky in the first place. Wouldn't it be better to at least make it disappear when you scroll down (and reappear when you start scrolling back up)?

Comment: @Ajedi32 No, it's already bad enough on mobile. I most certainly don't want that in my desktop.

Answer (score 17):

Would be better to make it dark, like the new GitHub nav:

[image]

Comment: Or like the old SO bar https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/830155273884930048

Comment: Yep exactly, just needs contrast

Comment: Then [GitHub would have to switch back too](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35656285#35656285)

Comment: I agree that there's too much white everywhere on both Stack and meta and it would be nice to make things a bit more distinct between the header and content, so you have my (up) vote here, just not black though ;-)

Comment: The new GitHub navigation looks really bad, and personally, I don’t want a tall navigation bar with that much contrast.

Comment: @Ryan That's because they (GitHub) know the difference between black and white and not white/bit less white / black/black'ish. Their new look makes a lot more sense, IMHO and others I'm sure.

Comment: The GitHub black is too dark and I find it very jarring. I think a lightgrey is a nice compromise.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: What?

Comment: I agree with dark, but not as dark as the one in your answer

Comment: Yes dark screen! This is horrible.

Answer (score 14):

### Green color of reputation

I think the old green of reputation is better than the new one, i suggest to change it to the old color.

[image: Old color of reputation]

and here the new :

[image: New color of reputation]

Comment: I got a rush everytime I saw that old green label with the white numbers on the black ground. Started to crave it even. Now, not so much, it is hard to find, have to look for it. Could even lead to me caring less about reputation, have to see. But just looking at it now makes me crave reputation again.

Answer (score 11):

I often have SO open in a 'split screen' arrangement, where I snap the window to occupy half the screen, or at times even less.

[image: half screen navbar]

When the window occupies half the screen, the nav is obscured by the scrollbar, and the search is almost uselessly narrow.

When I try to make the window even narrower, the nav remains fixed (you can't horizontal scroll the nav) and there is no way of accessing the far right buttons, except for resizing the window.

[image: narrow window nav]

I'm not knowledgeable enough to fix this, but I know this is something that need attention. My first thought would be a narrower logo (perhaps just the stack image) to free up some space.

Answer (score 10):

The toolbar on Stack Overflow Meta seems to understand that my screen is only 1024px wide (and when I make the window even narrower, the search box is squashed):

[image: Stack Overflow Meta toolbar]

However, on Stack Overflow itself, the "review queues" and "all SE sites" icons fall off the side (and when I make the window even narrower, the font in the search box becomes smaller, but the box itself retains the same width):

[image: Stack Overflow toolbar]

Using IE on a 1024x768 screen probably puts me in a tiny minority, but still, I was wondering whether this is by design?

Comment: do you have it sticky on both main and meta sites? or have you made it ubsticky somewhere?

Comment: @Paweł You're right, I made it unsticky on SO, and that's what causes it.

Answer (score 10):

[discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

## To get back something that looks like the old bar:

For Firefox/Chrome/Vivaldi, install the Stylish extension:

- [Link for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/stylish/)
- [Link for Chrome-based browsers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=fr)

Then install a custom theme that looks like the old one:

- Get this one that looks nice: https://userstyles.org/styles/138640/stack-black-slim-header?autofb#discussions-area
- Click on the "Install" button

Then do not forget to disable the stickyness in your profile ("Edit Profile & Settings" tab):

[image]

Then to get rid of those useless buttons (I'm talking about "Jobs", "Documentation", the search bar (you want to use google instead) and the [distracting review icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/870604)), add the following rules to your favorite ad-blocker:

```
stackoverflow.com###nav-jobs
stackoverflow.com##.js-review-button.-link
stackoverflow.com###nav-docs
stackoverflow.com##.js-search-field.f-input
```

*Et voilà*, something usable again:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Same thing [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343876/5180017) also!?

Comment: @Shashanth Yeah, cross-posted this practical solutions so people can see it

Comment: Ok. just kidding. +1 for the links.

Answer (score 9):

Height on this thing is freaking silly. Also I can't see icons behind notification counters.

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  .so-header {
    border-top: none !important;
  }
  .so-header .-logo,
  .so-header .-list,
  .so-header .-link,
  .so-header .my-profile {
    height: 34px !important;
    line-height: 34px !important;
  }
  .so-header .searchbar > * {
    height: 30px !important;
  }
  .so-header .indicator-badge {
    top: -1px !important;
    right: -10px !important;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Much better:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Based on this:

> @Floern there are plans to at least create some consistency between the two, they may be an incremental update (given the number of custom headers there are across the network sites). They're still in early exploration, but the short answer is yes. – Kurtis Beavers 3 hours ago

Can I put in another

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If it's possible, please at least move the site switcher/hamburger on other sites to the right, if you're going to keep this one there?  It is very confusing to my muscle memory to go left on some sites and right on others.

Comment: Yes it is, agree it's super-weird to have it one way in one place and a different way in the others.

Answer (score 8):

This is a common problem with most websites that have a sticky navigation bar as a header: <kbd>page-up</kbd> and <kbd>page-down</kbd> no longer work properly.  (Of course they still work fine if the sticky nav-bar is disabled).

Here are images to explain the situation.  The first page displays the bulleted list all the way to "Added keyboard shortcut to Help".

[image]

And then when you hit <kbd>page-down</kbd>, you see the next page of bulleted items.

[image]

Everything looks fine, right? WRONG! Here's what was missed:

[image]

The <kbd>page-up</kbd> and <kbd>page-down</kbd> keys need to be modified so that the scroll takes the height of the stick navigation bar into account.

Sorry for all the full-page images, but this is a full-page issue.

Answer (score 6):

I'd still like to see it decluttered further. Maybe...

1. Remove "Tags" and "Users", which I certainly use less often than the Help Center.
2. Remove "Questions", too, because ... why would I click that instead of the homepage again? It could at least be shrunk down to "Q&A".
3. Remove my profile glitter/guff (rep, badges), putting ...

   - ... an "account" link to `http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/<uid>` under the hamburger (in a position like "badges" in the achievements dropdown), since every other site on the web has such account settings on the far right.
   - ... the glitter near the top of the achievements dropdown if it's really important that it be kept.

That is, the only links and widgets I want are: Home, Notifications, Profile link, Search bar, Hamburger, Account Settings. I can tolerate Docs and Jobs, but would appreciate reduction in clutter where possible.

What's driving my clutter hate?

[image]

As seen here, my window is typically low-width, so I value the horizontal real estate up there.  I'd like to see the bar shown above look more like:

[image]

And similarly on the main site (albeit with Docs and Jobs).

Yes, I'm no designer, and my paint skills rise scarcely above a freehand circle.

Anyway, I generally like the changes and how responsive y'all have been to feedback.

---

**Edit:** I care about this a bit less now that I know the site's keyboard shortcuts. Since I can press "S" to get to the search bar, it's less important that I can find it above by muscle mouse memory.

I learned the shortcuts because the Help Center (removed from the top bar) can be reached with them.

Comment: The argument for "Questions" is that it presents a different list of questions than the one you get when you click the logo... though i prefer the list i get from the logo too.

Comment: How well does your design work for someone new to the site? How will you make them aware of the rep game? Badges? The different sections of the site? I get the "it doesn't work for me" argument - but we need to design for a lot of different users and use cases.

Comment: @Oded Are "Users" and "Tags" important parts of the site new users have to become familiar with? I didn't use them when I started and don't use them now. As a new user, I would find the distinct Home and Questions pages quite confusing. (Btw, I'm not saying to drop the Docs and Jobs links; they just didn't apply to the screenshot I took, of meta.) A new user would learn the gamification side through notifications and by visiting profiles. I'm just advocating going low-key with the rep and badge counts; whether new or not, no user needs to have such stats front-and-center all the time.

Comment: (And by front-and-center I mean taking up prime real estate in my window at all times, because I do like the floating top bar.)

Comment: @KevinB I don't think the questions link is useful at all, especially when you have the logo to click and the uncurated list of posts it provides can be added to the tabs below. I mentioned this in [my answer on the previous post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343449/1663001)

Comment: @Frank, you can disable the floating aspect:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: @Andy Thanks, I meant to say that I like the floating aspect. (And because I will leave it floating, I'll be seeing a lot of my profile flair, along with the other stuff.)

Comment: Doesn’t SO collect usage metrics on UI elements? I don’t think I ever used the Users or Badges tab deliberately in months.

Comment: @poke YMMV. Most users don't have ~600 badges, so they are probably interested still in what it takes to earn some of them. I have a few badges myself but visit the badges page quite regularly.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to make the logo (and the link around it) fill up all space to the left of the screen - I use it quite frequently to get to the home page, and it is hard to hit in the current state. Especially on Stack Overflow, since the logo is so small.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't the site-switcher button have 2 lines in the middle, just like the original stack exchange logo?

[image]

I'm not asking for changing it, but was just wondering if it's only because 3 lines fits better with other logos in the bar.

Comment: This has been asked before, Let me see if I can find the link to this specific change request

Comment: [Here we are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343151/4029561)

Comment: tl;dr this is [status-bydesign]

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer the Questions tab going away and it's space being taken up by increasing the size of the logo. The questions tab as it is is redundant because you can get the same list of "newest" questions by clicking the logo and then the newest tab, and I find the list of questions that you get when you click the logo to be far more relevant/useful when looking for interesting questions.

As far as the other three tabs, I don't see much of a reason to have "Users" front and center, SO isn't a social network and doesn't revolve around individual users, so this tab is mostly useless in my opinion. Tags I can see as being somewhat useful for getting stats and information on tags.

I'd rather Documentation not take up so much space in the Nav. It's underregulated at the moment with the 100 rep bar for reviews with no tag based restriction, and not enough emphasis on stopping plagiarism. It's just in a state right now where I don't think we should be pushing more people to it until we actually know what it is supposed to be.

Comment: eh, i guess adblock works well enough to get rid of questions/users/review icon. Too bad that won't get me the larger logo

Comment: This gist however will https://gist.github.com/tentonaxe/b2e22f5d8e85b5d515939ebaa23fb656

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think it would be better like this:

[image]

If you agree, here is a user-style override for you:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  .so-header .navigation,
  .so-header .my-profile .-rep,
  .so-header .my-profile .-badges,
  .so-header .secondary-nav > .-list > li:nth-of-type(2),
  .so-header .secondary-nav > .-list > li:nth-of-type(3) { display: none }
}
```

(I decided I didn't need to be reminded of my rep on every page, either.)

Comment: That's actually very similar to a userscript I'm currently using. It doesn't make much sense for non-power-users though.

Comment: I also got rid of the bright orange bar at the top, for  some reason i found it very annoying. What do you use to add your scripts to pages? I use chrome extension Style Bot.

Comment: @Andrew I prefer Firefox, so [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=userprofile).

Answer (score 4):

My name is [Yakk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk).

You [moved my Cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Moved_My_Cheese%3F).

Prepare to [Dye](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BQ5SAQ).

Problems: Lots of vertical space consumed.  Low contrast.  Unclear what opens up a pop-down, and what navigates away from the page, without clicking and seeing what it does.  Tool tips missing on half of the options (everything Search and left).

Answer (score 3):

I think the sticky navigation header is:

- A waste of space. The worst case is probably Google Plus design.
- Distracting. Welcoming the user to jump around, but not stimulating to do anything useful.
- Is unsuitable for "long read" sites.

Stack Overflow is a site with long questions and long answers. Sticky elements are cumbersome and are totally unworthy, while the main attention should be on the question, the answers, and the comments.

**EDIT:** There is "disable stickyness" setting in the profile. It's probably ok this way.

Comment: I agree. I made use of the configuration setting that allows turning it off. (in your profile settings)

Answer (score 3):

I just scanned through the question, the answers, and the blogpost, and didn't find any mentioning of this. Forgive me if I missed this.

Why did you decide to omit the **site name** ("Stack Overflow")? It is here on meta, but not on the main site (neither on question pages nor the front page). Do you think your logo is readable enough so the text is not needed?

Comment: The full logo is present on the logged out version. If you're logged in, we think the logo is enough because, hey, you're logged in.

Comment: See [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?page=2&tab=oldest#comment444533_343275)

Comment: Same thought here!! I like the "stackoverflow" text, and I like to see it even though I signed in!!

Answer (score 3):

## Search Input

[image]

I think the search input should be fix it is really hard to move to the left every time you want to search something, so fix it can be better and easy.

Consider you already tip something `[java]` and hit enter now, try to change java to something else! now you should to move the cursor to the left so you can edit it, did you find this practice? for me i think it is a pert of time to move every time to the left for that i suggest to make it fix for example like the previous version https://meta.stackexchange.com/ , plus i don't find any necessity to make it resized every time, i'm wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: _"It should be fixed."_ is unclear if you don't clearly describe what's wrong.

Comment: @Cerbrus Consider you already tip something `[java]` and hit enter now, try to change java to something else! now you should to move the cursor to the left so you can edit it, did you find this practice? for me i think it is a pert of time to move every time to the left for that i suggest to make it fix for example like the previous version http://meta.stackexchange.com/ , plus i don't find any necessity to make it resized every time, i'm wrong?

Comment: Yea, I don't see the problem. Just use your keyboard to clear the field ([Ctrl+A])

Comment: @Cerbrus not every one know that, what if i want to change just a letter, whatever i hope this can be changed

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about this problem, but it looks like the wording is just still under costruction.

While other `title` attributes show texts with leading capital letter, this breaks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is also very confusing if you browse multiple sites since the other sites have the original top navbar. Each child site should have similar layout and navigation so the flow is the same on any site. Even sites that are along the same computer programming genre line ([code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/))have the original navbar and for me it is confusing switching to a child site and having a completely unique navbar when the old one was fine.

If you are going to make the change on one site, it should happen across all the sites.

Comment: You may expect generalization in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: And this is confirmed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343268/is-the-new-top-bar-going-to-be-rolled-out-to-all-se-sites-in-the-future)

Answer (score 2):

**Hamburger site selector not needed**

If the site selector was done as a dropdown from the site icon in the way it currently is on the Stack Overflow dropdown, the hamburger menu could be done away with. That would yield enough space for, say, a Help menu.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The difficulty here is that the top bar is split into two sides, to match the dual-column layout of the site. Your user-data and everything right of it is in the same column as the related questions and other side material. While the search bar and everything left of it is in the main text column. If you remove something from the right column, it won't free up space in the left column.

Comment: I see. But the idea is not totally burgered: the search box could be a little bit narrower, seeing as it expands to cover the links to the left of it when it is clicked. The dropdown triangle does not need to be as grossly sized as I crudely drew it. The help menu ("?"), which I read that many people would like to be able to see regardless of reputation points, would take the place of the burger.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but I loathe the new nav bar.

Would you mind making it switchable so I can choose the old one?

Key points of discontent:

1. It's too big.
2. It's not black so it doesn't stand out.
3. Search should be on the right. Communication icons should be in the middle (where I naturally look).
4. The old one was perfect, familiar and complemented natural human behaviour.

Looks like change for change's sake, without user consultation - never a good idea.

Comment: Whilst I agree with you on the whole I think all these points have been raised separately. I do prefer the old one but I've now got used to the new one. I'm lucky enough though to have a big enough monitor where it doesn't impact much.

Comment: @Bugs I think we should keep raising it until it gets changed back. It's made the site unpleasant to use.

Comment: In total, the nav now takes up *less* vertical space than before. That gripe I don't understand at all.

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

A "To Top" button would be nice as an addition in the header (IMHO).

Sidenote: My answer may be off-topic, so let me know if I should delete this and post it in meta as a feature request instead.

I.e.:

[image]

or as an arrow:

[image]

Or just like on http://php.net does, having an arrow show up on the bottom right soon as we start scrolling.

There is room for it, unless they're reserving that space for something else.

Comment: Bonus points if it is an up arrow icon rather than the words 'To Top' :-D

Comment: @TylerH That's a good point. I'll make another screencap with arrows. Thanks.

Comment: What happened to captain jack sparrow?

Comment: I assume this would only show up if the topbar is sticky? (Would be pretty pointless for the non-sticky one)

Comment: @TylerH added an arrow - not the best but it shows the idea.

Comment: @Floern either when the page is starting to scroll or always make it visible. It was a general idea. Or at the bottom right when it starts to scroll just like on php.net

Comment: It would be nice to hear from the downvoters as to why they think this isn't a good idea, or if I should have posted this on meta as a feature request.

Comment: @TinyGiant He took a break for a while since he couldn't find good tasting Swedish meatballs in his corner of the world.

Comment: I read *"Or at the bottom right when it starts to scroll just like on php.net"* as *"Or at the bottom right when it starts to scroll just take them to php.net"*

Comment: @TinyGiant I wrote: *"Or just like on http://php.net does, having an arrow show up on the bottom right soon as we start scrolling."* - Meaning that when we start scrolling down the pages (here) that an (to top) arrow shows up, unless I didn't explain that properly.

Comment: No, you were perfectly eloquent. My brain just interpreted your comment to floern in a way that made me laugh.

Comment: Press the Home button.

Comment: @Ryan I can't see mine anymore; it's been wiped off by hitting it so many times :p and I don't have a paintbrush that small to paint one on. Ah, some old skills of mine should be used if I can find one *haha!*

Comment: Actually @Ryan You should have gone through the comments under the question first before doing what you did. I posted one in there which I'm keeping as well as this answer. However, I will delete my answer if it starts getting too many downvotes. But I'm pretty sure the (other) mods/techs might have seen my answer and may take it into consideration. If you are part of the decision makers, then you let me know so I can stop making a fool of myself.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I have no idea what you’re saying.

Comment: @TylerH especially not in Times New Roman.

Comment: Usually, buttons like this appear at the bottom of the window (Sticky). Not in a sticky menu bar.

Comment: @Cerbrus near the bottom, following *"Or.."*

Comment: Hey! you also have that cutted-off pixel bug which they call "Blurry icons edge case 1 - not reproducible" (last bug in the list). +1 just for that screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

Remarks on order and contents:

[image]

- Search bar is too small and is wrong place. Search should *always* be at top right. It should be as wide as possible, so remaining goal is to reduce wasted space.
- Space at top right is wasted. Logo should be all the way against the left margin.
- I care what my rep is but not how many badges I have. Eliminate the badges display.
- I care what notifications and new awarded rep I have, and that is of a totally different degree of importance from the review queue. Move my rep, notifications, and awards all the way to the left, immediately after the site logo.

So, my proposed order is:

- Logo
- My icon and rep (no badges)
- My notifications and new awards
- Questions, Jobs, Doc, Tags, Users [Okay, I'd like to eliminate the Documentation but I figure you won't go for that]
- Review queue, hamburger
- Search. No white space anywhere, so Search can now be much wider to fill what is left.

So, more like this (the Search is a little *too* big here, but this is just a sketch):

[image]

Comment: you... realize that on larger monitors that'd put the logo waaaay off to the left of the page content, right?

Answer (score -1):

*edit: Found comment [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update/343815#comment447978_343780) via duplicate request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343818/324105 after reading Kevin B's comment.*

---

Can the option to disable fixed (sticky) positioning *please* be global across the network, rather than per-site ?

I switched it off here in meta, and then found it was back on again when I visited the non-meta site, and I had to find the settings option all over again!

I don't think it makes any sense at all for that behaviour to vary on a per-site basis.  Either users like it or they don't, and it's very annoying to switch it off, and then find it's "back on again" when you visit a different site on the network.

Switching it off once doesn't bother me at all.  Having to switch it off over and over across a period of weeks or months is going to make me genuinely irritated.

Comment: it will be eventually.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that in general we should improve and innovate.

However, the **dark Top Nav** was a *very distinctive* element, and personally I would not have changed the color, at the most a lighter or darker gray. This is too light!

Am I okay for the rest, the new layout of the icons and other features fine, I like it.

However, I continue to be a firm supporter of the **dark Top Nav**.

The white nav gives me a feeling of emptiness and loss.

Comment: The white nav gives _me_ a sense of openness and prosperity.

Answer (score -2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Please make the notification numbers go past the top of the icons when hovered. CSS:

```
.so-header .secondary-nav .-item._active .indicator-badge, .so-header .secondary-nav .-item .-link.topbar-icon-on .indicator-badge, .so-header .secondary-nav .-item .-link:hover .indicator-badge {
  top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ask Question is not visible when scrolled down, shouldn't it be also available like the top bar all the time. Also Top Bar Icons are very confusing, Review queues icon is not good and same goes for message one. For message we could rather have the below specified change

[image]

Answer (score -21):

This is how it looks at me.

[image]

First I've thought there is some bug or unwaited interaction between my development or security extensions and your page. But not. You crapped something again.

I can't understand! I really can't understand!

You really don't have anything to fix, except trashing good, acknowledged, beautiful parts of your site?

*Would you like to get a list of some year long bugs and missing (trivial) features from the meta SE? Why the ... you won't work on these, why are you working to crap what once worked?*

No... you won't even read this post. So happens with every company growing too large. :-(

P.s. Any idea, what is that orange line on the top top to do? Hm???

P.s.2. Your previous remembered "unneeded thing fixed, needed thing crapped" change was as you "extended" the user pages on a way that you made the users description invisible. You really don't have any better to do? Really? For example:

- Why the heck the post suggestions don't work on the meta sites?
- When will all your sites work with https pretty well (correct keys, no http content reference if https was requested)?
- When will be the docs SE finally ready, not a pre-stable beta?
- When will we see the real size of the review queues on the main review page?

Comment: The orange line is a border, it doesn't "do" anything beyond providing visual separation between the content of the page and the UI of the browser bars. Other than that, there doesn't appear to be much constructive about this post, unfortunately.

Comment: I agree --  they fixed something that wasn't broken and the fix is arguably worse

Comment: @TylerH My first idea was that there is some positioning bug and the top taskbar elements somehow jumped out of their border...

Comment: @peterh: Look, they've explained the reason for the floating top-bar many times these past few weeks. There are many threads on Meta where they've discussed this.

Comment: @NicolBolas It seems I have to implement an external css to make the SO usable again... I hope they don't plan to extend it to the other sites... :-(

Comment: @peterh: Or you could just *use the option they provided* to make it not float. And to say that the site is not usable even with a floating top bar is hyperbolic.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is LESS ergonomic, it is LESS beautiful (honestly... disgusting), it tries to fix some working, while the whole META SE is full with never-to-implement, longwanted feature requests!

Comment: @peterh: Well, I think it's just as ergonomic and beautiful as the old site. Unless you can back your opinion up with reasoning and facts, you can't expect reasonably expect others to take them seriously. Explain what about the site is "less ergonomic". Explain what is "less beautiful". And so forth. A reasonable explanation of why you feel this way is going to be far more useful than just declaring "this is bad and you're stupid for doing it!"

Comment: @NicolBolas It is... **UGLY**! Oh my god I never ever seen something killed on this way! They've made the search box auto growing on focus! So their around 1000px wide site is now essentially a vertical track in my 1920px wide browser, and this search box is autogrowing on the top of this track! I think, the idea of "fluid design" didn't arrive into the StackExchange in the last 15 years! Maybe in 2035!

Comment: tl;dr Change Bad! Hulk Smash!

Comment: *"P.s. Any idea, what is that orange line on the top top to do? Hm???"* - It seems to make it distinct to the Stack's new orange color logo and the gray line on top in this section suggests it, since it too matches the gray meta logo. Btw, **not** my downvote here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, slowly I understood...

Comment: @peterh: "*So their around 1000px wide site is now essentially a vertical track in my 1920px wide browser, and this search box is autogrowing on the top of this track!*" OK, that's a useful comment: the top bar, coupled with a 2x wide view of the site, causes problems. I'm not entirely sure how, since the right side of the search bar is always in the same place. But that's at least a comment which is *actionable*.

Comment: @NicolBolas No. It is not an useful comment. You reformulated a problem well, that is ok, but you misunderstood. Once I will explain it for you.

Comment: @peterh I noticed it soon as I switched back to meta and noticed the top gray line and the logo ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am talking about something quite different, not from a bug, but from a conceptual trash. I am talking about a fixed-width page, which width is MUCH smaller as the todays common browser width, and they are making on-focus growing elements to use this NARROW vertical track which is the site content, as effective as they can. They should make the site simply MORE WIDE, and if they fear that it will seem bad on smaller screens, they should use FLUID DESIGN. On the way it now works, is extremely lame.

Comment: @peterh *"they should use FLUID DESIGN"* - I have often wondered why it doesn't work like that. I'm thinking that they want us to download their mobile app for screen sizes smaller than a home pc box. However, that question may be more fit as a discussion and/or feature request on meta. I'm sure they have their reason(s) though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Google for "media query"... I can't imagine that they don't know this, with their development resources it should have been long made.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But, for example, a long-standing bug or missing feature: post edit suggestion simply doesn't exist on the meta sites. Yes, they could "explain" it, why... maybe it had been better to fix it, instead "explain" it...

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you have a link to an explanation to the floating behaviour? I can’t find a link and I find it puzzling. It’s less bad than on other sites where the header adds zero functionality but it’s still something I’m glad I can disable, and for which I do not understand the design rationale.

Comment: @Fred-ii- They don't use fluid design, because as a company grows larger, so become its products worser. Check, for example, the "pages" of the Oracle... they are 100x bigger company as the StackExchange and their pages are on the level of the late nineties... the same is happening to the SE now.

Comment: @peterh sorry but there's nothing else I can discuss about this; take it up on meta for discussion please.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The [blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1) explains it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Particularly the *“I scroll down and read the question.”* is funny, because this taskbar can't be scrolled out of the screen ;-)

Comment: @peterh: Yes, that's the point. By making it so that it is always there, it's also always *available*. And therefore, users who didn't know those things *even existed* will be able to find them and make use of them.

Comment: Peterh, you are entitled to an opinion, but you can't objectively say the new design is ugly, because ugly is an opinion. The main thing that SE cares about is the average user's behavior, as determined by their stats on user engagement. Since the new design is increasing user engagement, the new design is better from their perspective. It's unfortunate that you don't like the new design, but it has nothing to do with SE becoming a large company.

Comment: @AndyMercer If the SE would take care to the new users, they would migrate the offtopic questions to their intended site, instead simply closing them... no, not this is what I see, I see a big company doing a little bit of pseudo-work, and mostly nothing development. This thread is about the pseudo-work.

Comment: @NicolBolas OMG, even the https support is buggy on most meta sites, they simply didn't set up the keys correctly, and they don't even try to fix it! And you are talking from everything, except any problem!