# Miss the old top navigation

Tags: discussion, top-bar

I really love this site and respect these programmers and designers. They design this amazing site. Many details of the design makes people admire.

But I really like the old top nav. It looks clearer and more practical. `Jobs` or `Tags` or `Users` - these nav tags are of little use to me. And the dark theme make those tag clearer. And I can change Stack Exchange sites more easily.

The above is my opinion.

Comment: Give it a little bit of time - 15 minutes is really not enough time to get an impression.

Comment: You might want to post your feedback as an answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) instead

Comment: *sniff* I miss it too. Wows me, it was a great friend to me in some really dark times, always there right beside me, never judged me - I mean I remember basking in the warmth of that orange hue and just feeling like everything was going to be fine (or, at least, that I'd get an answer to something). But it's tired, it did all it came here to do, and we probably asked way too much of it by making it stay as long as we did. It's resting, now, all cuddled up in an assisted UX facility, waiting to take on its golden years.

Comment: It's rather frustrating. I now have to think when I want to click on something. Getting rid of a few years of habits is HARD.

Comment: it is not consistent, on the right part (the 4 symbols.), which one opens a menu and which opens a new page.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah,it's a really good advice.