# How many of you like the new navigation bar? Would you like to be able to revert to the old navigation bar?

Tags: discussion, new-nav, top-bar

I'm personally not happy with the new navigation bar. I think it's just too much and simply overpowering. - a navigation bar is meant to be simple and plain (just like the old one was).

A few comments which I would like to highlight from: [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update)

> Why do you people have to keep changing things that aren't broken? This is a Q&A site, not some web brogrammer muscle-flexing exposition.

This brings to mind the famous quote "if it's not broke, don't fix it".

> I hate the new nav bar. I dunno if I'm just not used to it or if its
>   actually bad. I kinda liked having my new notifications inbox not
>   tucked away in the far right corner where I never look.

I completely agree with this. Not only are the notifications now tucked away, but they're not eye catching! Before, you could clearly see when you received a notification as it's container would be bright red. Now, it's a tiny little square which you have to look closely if you want to notice!.

> I just wanted to add that the "old minimal black topbar" felt iconic
>   and was a huge part of the StackOverflow identity.

This user is right. It's as if the "identity" of Stackoverflow has been thrown away by the new navigation bar. This also backs up my idea of the new navigation bar being "too much" and simply overpowering.

Since the new navigation bar has been released, there's been many topics posted in the meta requesting for the old navigation bar to be available for us to use (or something along the lines of that):

- [Can we have the old nav back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343868/can-we-have-the-old-nav-back) - 7 people upvoted this.
- [How to go back to the old top bar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343735/how-to-go-back-to-the-old-top-bar) - 111 people upvoted this.
- [Miss the old top navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343748/miss-the-old-top-navigation) - 7 people upvoted this.

I posted a feature request at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343906/allow-us-to-switch-between-the-old-and-new-navigation-bar, asking for the option to change back to the old navigation bar and within minutes, it was marked as status-declined. This implies to me that the staff here are not listening:

WE WANT TO BE ABLE TO USE THE OLD NAVIGATION BAR!

To prove my point, I would like to find out your opinion - do you honestly like the new navigation bar? Or would you like the option of using the old one? Please just leave a few lines in an answer or a comment.

Remember, it's the community's voice that counts.

Comment: Did you happen to read the [blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1) explaining why we updated the top bar?  It explains that the old bar was, in fact, broken.

Comment: To be honest, I hated it at the start. Now, I couldn't care less. I realized I rarely even look at the top bar, except when checking notifications/review queues. And since stickiness is an option, it's really a non issue, since 99% of the time I've scrolled down, anyway. Ideally I'd have it a *little* bit shorter, but, meh.

Comment: I agree that the new Top Bar sucks.  Much rather go back to the old.

Answer (score 18):

> *"it was marked as status-declined. This implies to me that the staff here are not listening:"*

"A staff member applied a tag only staff can apply. They're not listening."

You, sir, are the one that's not listening.

It's practically impossible to maintain 2 *completely* different versions of the menu. Yet SE is open to (and looking into) having a darker style, partially because of the amount of support [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343106#343106) got.

Note: I don't like the new menu, but I can absolutely understand why going back isn't an option.

Comment: It's not 'practically impossible'. I can think of at least three ways to do it.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, just that it's a pain in the ass to maintain.

Comment: This is ridulous.  The old top bar was easy, and reliable.  We need to revert it back already.