# Bring back the Ask Question button

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

With the [new top navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update), how do I ask a question?

[image: width=800]

Oh, I need to scroll right. Or make my browser window very wide — if I make it full-width on a cheapo monitor (1920x1080) in portrait mode (which is the only way to have a decent height), I do see the “Ask Question” button. Most of it anyway.

[image: width=1080]

I know that you only officially support ridiculously wide window sizes because you assume that nobody makes use of that geeky stuff out of Xerox that allows fitting more than one program's window on the screen. But even with degraded experience, basic functionality should work. And asking a question is pretty basic. Ok, it does work, but it's gotten pretty hard to discover, now that it's out there in the sidebar (i.e. the place where sites put the unimportant stuff).

This is especially bad for users who aren't logged in, who have to notice that little bit of blue text, way [outside the natural center of attention](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/), with no surrounding frame to guide them, sandwich between the huge house ad and the paid ads. (The luck of the draw gave me an ad that was even more blue-on-white than this one before, but I reloaded and got a more diversely colored one before I took the screenshot.)

[image: front page]

For my own use I can and will fix it in a user style (though it's annoying to have to maintain a user style). But this is really bad for new users. Veteran curmudgeons notwithstanding, we *do* want people to ask questions on Stack Exchange.

So please make the “Ask Question” button easy to find.

Comment: What is seriously unclear here?

Comment: the Ask Question button is in the same spot it has always been in and i've compared the new top bar on SO to the other sites which don't have it. the only difference to the button is that there isn't as much white space on the top and bottom

Comment: for a comparison, [on SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ2en.png)  and [on SE Meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxtdp.png)

Comment: @Memor-X No, the Ask Question button used to be in the very tall row containing other buttons (the toplevel tabs Questions, Tags, etc.). It's roughly in the same X-Y location, but in terms of finding it, that's completely different. It used to be in a row of buttons and now it's in the column with the ads.

Comment: @Gilles i see your point if we are talking about how HTML wise the button is now in the sidebar for question lists and the question-header when in question but most of the time but it's still in the same spot with less unused space above and bellow because there is no, at most 143px forced height `div` for the headerw where it is roughly vertically center aligned (which is smaller on some sites, 143px is SE Meta but a Beta's can be 120px while Arqade's is 109px).

Comment: (cont.) also *"I know that you only officially support ridiculously wide window sizes"* if i recall a few years ago W3C's standard for minimum desktop web page widths was updated from 800px to 1080px. SE's Desktop Design has always been (to my knowledge) ~1060px (going by the size of the header that the Ask Question button wasin) the new top nav has the same max width, i don't see how this is ridiculous unless your on a mobile device in which case we're talking about a different issue here

Comment: Question title is a little confusing because it makes it sounds like this is something new caused by the recent change but *roughly in the same X-Y location* would mean this was an existing issue.

Comment: @BSMP No, this is a new issue. The button used to be in a very visible row  with other buttons. It is now in a column with ads. People don't look for a button thinking “oh, it's about in that location” (unless they're site regulars already, in which case I'm confident they'll have no problems finding the button), they go “hey, I'm looking for a button for one of the site's main features, where could it be?” The button used to be in a nondescript X-Y location, it's now in roughly the same nondescript X-Y location, but the method to find it has change completely.

Comment: So the browser width part isn't the issue?

Comment: @Memor-X I'm one of apparently a small minority who use a window operating system, which shows multiple windows on the screen at the same time, side by side (possibly with overlap). All desktop users have an OS that's capable of that, not every user makes use of it, but it's a pretty basic functionality *that's on by default in every major operating system*.

Comment: @BSMP Having a narrow browser window makes it worse, but the issue is present even with a wide window.

Comment: So you're not asking for the button itself back, but the background color for that row?

Comment: @BSMP No, I'm asking to make the button easier to find. If it can be done without changing its location, fine, but given the location, I doubt it. Moving it left, where it won't require scrolling to the right even without having a maximized window, would be safer.

Comment: "This is especially bad for users who aren't logged in, who have to notice that little bit of blue text, way outside the natural center of attention, with no surrounding frame to guide them, sandwich between the huge house ad and the paid ads" Is this really a problem considering the fact that you can't ask questions without logging in?

Comment: @dorukayhan Yes, it's a problem. It's already hard to ask a question on SO, and we're making it even harder.

Comment: "It's already hard to ask a question on SO" SO wouldn't have severe quality problems if it was actually hard to ask a question.