# Can we have the old nav back?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

This is an honest question.

I have been reading the comments in the post [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update), and it is safe to say, almost everyone seems to dislike it, some more vocal than the others.

I commented on a post made by [philip-kirkbride](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/773263/philip-kirkbride) critizing the new layout (post is now removed) that I personally appreciate the fixes and improvement, but the aesthetic feels definately a downgrade.

I like putting my SO profile in my CV, because the design was elegant and had more enterprise-ish feel into it, hence my profile would seem legit but now it different.

So, SE being a community-driven site, if the community wants the old nav back, can we have it or not?

Comment: "*I have been reading the comments in the post Top Navigation Update, and it is safe to say, almost everyone seems to dislike it, some more vocal than the others.*" I don't get that sense at all. Oh sure, there are vocal condemnations of it. But look at the votes on actual posts: they're for specific "improvements" to the top nav; they're not desiring its outright removal. The highest voted post that asks for its removal is only in the mid-60s, and even that one lists specific problems that could easily be solved in the existing paradigm without reverting it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I disagree.  I get the sense that MORE people dislike the new bar.

Comment: Yes! Old one back please!

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate, it's different from the supposed duplicate post.

Comment: Yeah, i was asking SO rather than for a chrome pluging to change the nav. But someone didn't like the question I guess.