# Unanswered question block contains wrong author

Tags: support, top-bar

I see a bug in a list of questions. I see a [question of another author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252894/keeping-backend-validation-in-sync-with-frontend-validation) with my account set as an author.

[image: example].

I just edited my **answer** 1 hour ago. Is it a listed bug?

UPD. `modified answer` would be better than just `modified`.

Comment: I've read here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update?cb=1 a tip to post all bugs to a `top-bar` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered the question.

As you can see it says above your name: `modified 1 hour ago`.

Comment: I usually see there author's name, not the one, who answers or edits.

Comment: You will see there the people who edited or answered a question too. This has been the case for a long time now.

Comment: Looks like this place is for the one who made **any** action with question or any its answer...

Comment: @shukshin.ivan - no. If you comment on a question it won't show up there.

Comment: Did it take place before redesign? If so, I am too inattentive...

Comment: It has been like that for years.

Comment: years... Thanks. But `modified answer` would be better for usability than just `modified`.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan If you click on that text, it takes you the post that was edited.

Comment: Right. But it is not unanswered - I've answered. Why is it in Unanswered list?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Stack Overflow only considers questions that either have an answer with a positive score or an accepted answer as answered. [The 'unanswered' tab has multiple answered questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292013)