# Ask Question button background color

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar

After the [top nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) went live I just noticed that "ask question" button style is different for external users in compared to the logged in users.

So for logged in user it appears

[image]

And for external users it appears

[image]

So can these two styles not be made similar or better to set the background color to blue?

What do you think?

Comment: You can't ask a question when you're not logged in.  Feature, not a bug.