# Why does the 'Ask Question' button change colour between tabs?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

I was just flicking through the tabs at the top, when I noticed the styling of the 'Ask Question' button changes.

For example, on 'month' it's white...
[image]

Then on 'week' it's blue...
[image]

Weirdly, I can't always get it to reproduce the same outcome; sometimes 'week', or 'hot' will be white, sometimes they're all blue, sometimes I click on one tab, it's white, change to another tab and back, and then the colour changes to blue...

I saw this question: [Ask Question button background color](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343934/ask-question-button-background-color) - which suggests that the white buttons are shown when the user is not logged in, but I'm logged in for all cases.

Is this a bug, or some form of A/B test, or something else?

Comment: It’s blue for me on Main, but red and _outlined_ on Meta. The only difference in CSS classes is `s-btn__primary` vs. `s-btn__outlined`.

Comment: @Xufox - The same effect appears to be happening on Meta too... On one tab I'm getting the red outlined button, but on another I get the solid black button.

Comment: Can confirm: In chrome it is only blue for me for the "interesting" tab, in firefox incognito mode also for the "featured", same in chrome incognito, and in normal firefox.

Comment: Opera : Blue on main except for the 'hot' tab. On meta normal except for the 'active' tab

Comment: Given the apparent inconsistency of the behavior, I'm inclined to guess it's A/B testing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's a charitable interpretation. :) Alas, it's some combination of caching and ... I don't even know what instead. The outlined style is supposed to be shown to anonymous users, and the filled in is for logged in. It's not *supposed* to change between tabs (or be red on MSO at all, for that matter), but it does. It's on my list of things to dig into this coming week.

Comment: For me, it's showing button with blue background only for 'interesting' tab, for everything else, it shows white background with blue border.

Comment: For me it is normally filled for all tabs, except hot and weekly, there no/white fill and blue outline. Using FF 60.0.2 64b on MacOS Sierra 16G29

Comment: @AdamLear May be related: When I switch between tabs, there's one tab with a different number for featured questions than all the others.

Comment: I was looking at this the other day and it changed styles several times in a row when I refreshed *on the same tab* .  Figured someone was just back there somewhere tinkering with the stylesheet.  What's weird is it's still going on here days later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We fixed this a while back, but I figured I'd write up some of the details anyway.

The original design intent was to show the outlined button to anonymous users and the filled-in style to logged in users. This worked fine and dandy while the button itself was in the sidebar. Once the button moved into the "main bar", we ran into problems. We cache the rendered question lists on the front page, so the style would switch depending on which type of user hit the page first when it was time to refresh the cache.

I spent some time looking into doing separate caches for anonymous vs logged in users, but ultimately we just switched the button styling to be the same in both cases. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯