# Include the Help link in the source of the new navbar

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Include the Help link in the source of the navbar, and then simply hide it for high-rep users. That would allow plugins like Stylish, Greasemonkey, etc. to show the link, for those of us who still want it.

This would also require that the Help link have an ID (which it currently doesn't), similar to the main navigation links.

Here's a quick mockup - I added the link to the secondary nav, next to the inbox, as that seemed the logical place to group it:

[image: Navbar tweak - adds help link back]

It doesn't really take up much room.