# Improving edit queue to encourage in-depth edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, reputation, quality-improvement

I understand why there is an **edit queue** on Stack Overflow. It seems necessary to avoid "flooding" and lighten the payload, but in the end, I am wondering if it is not detrimental to quality (in the sense that it may discourage some serious people to contribute, even though they can get `+2` reputation).

When I edit a post (question or answer), I like to take some time to do it well. I generally fix typos, correct grammatical errors, clarify meaning, improve formatting and add/remove tags. Sometimes this takes a couple of minutes, and when I click *Save Edits*, I often get:

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

This is extremely frustrating, especially when the edit queue remains in this state for a "long" period of time. When this is happening, I generally cancel my edit, so all my modifications are lost.

In my humble opinion, edit queue encourages quick edits. From what I observed, many edits are superficial (the most common edit is probably a minor tag reorganization). **This is great**, *but* it should not forestall in-depth edits.

A good way to avoid frustration would be to take into account the **action**, not just the **result**. What I mean is that the edit option should be disabled, not only when the edit queue is full, but also when a given number of SO members are editing a post. For example, given the limit (200 reviews), we could disable the edit option when 180 edits have been made **and** 20 users are currently editing.

Would it be possible to implement this feature? What do you think about it?

I guess I will not have this problem anymore above the **2000 reputation** threshold because there edits are applied immediately. However, I think users with **500+ reputation** can make relevant reviews. Frustrating them with the current edit queue is not the best way to promote thorough edits, in spite of the small reputation bonus after validation...

---

**EDIT (May 12)**

Following the discussion, it appears that there are a couple of alternative solutions to mitigate this problem...

[Bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6375113/bugs) proposes to create a separate queue for tag-only edits. This idea is interesting because, given the amount of tag-only edits on Stack Overflow, it will probably reduce congestion dramatically.

[Dan Lowe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2449905/dan-lowe) goes further and suggests to grant immediate tag-only edits to established users below 2000 reputation. This proposal is relevant too because it will remove a significant part of the current edit queue and will discourage people who are tempted by quick edits to earn two reputation points.

[Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) recommends a strict separation of editing operations to get more "atomic" edits. It would certainly speed up the reviewing process because reviewers could identify immediately if the edit is about tags, whitespace, or code formatting.

To my mind, rewarding in-depth edits accordingly would also be beneficial. Currently, whether you add a single tag or refactor the entire post, you get `+2` reputation. But for people who prefer reputation farming to quality, it is more profitable to make 10 edits in 5 minutes than 10 edits in 20 minutes... By the way, edits that make the post worse should also be penalized with a `-1` reputation.

---

**EDIT (May 23)**

I recently reached 2000 reputation points and got access to the *Suggested Edits* queue. After a couple of days reviewing edits, it seems that my initial intuition is now verified: tag-only edits (or at least superficial edits) are too frequent, even on awful posts where there are tons of possible improvements. In-depth edits, which fix everything in a post, are rare and precious. Most edits nowadays must be improved, not just approved. So when I see a remarkable edit with substantial efforts behind, I would like to reward the editor. But when I see an average edit, I do not want to grant free reputation.

From my perspective, we need a real incentive (reputation or badge) to increase the number of thorough edits and avoid reputation farming. Reviewers could have the following evaluation options:

- **Good Edit:** `+2` reputation
- **Acceptable Edit:** `0` reputation
- **Bad Edit:** `-1` reputation

Preferably, bad edits (rejected ones) as well as acceptable edits should not be taken into account to get badges like `Editor`, `Strunk & White` or `Copy Editor`. Of course, 2000+ rep users would not be concerned by this new policy because their edits are applied immediately, are supposed to be good (aren't they?) and do not saturate the edit queue. However, for 2000- rep users, I think it is a good idea to make quality standards more stringent for edits. Good habits come from a better education...

Comment: It seems that time has passed... The edit queue is often full. Now everytime I edit a question and spend a couple of minutes on it, I feel pressure when I click *Save Edits*. Lots of my edits were lost because of that...

Comment: I seriously doubt there is ever a time when 20 users are editing the same post, especially since I believe it blocks those with <2k rep from editing a post which is already being edited. It used to be we could reject edits that were "too minor". Now that we can't, I can see that it might encourage more, smaller edits (like changing i to I or updating indentation only).

Comment: 20 users at the same time is unlikely, but this was an extreme example. From my experience, I face a full edit queue really often. I would say 1/3 of my edits are lost this way...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: **Years** passed between removing "Too Minor" and the edit queue filling. They aren't related. The filling queue is just a consequence of SO's distributed moderation/privilege thresholds not scaling properly: Close was first, then LQP, and now other queues are following the same pattern of constant, unavoidable congestion as the site gets larger and reviewers tire.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I didn't say there was a causal relationship between the two. But the lack of a reject reason for "too minor" certainly doesn't encourage taking one's time to fix all of the issues with a post, does it?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: No, but since it *may* encourage easier-to-review edits that can clear out much faster, I'm not sure it's much of a loss. Much worse are edits that handle tags wrongly, add useless formatting, or pointlessly shuffle deckchairs on *Titanic*ly bad questions. Now, if we had a predefined category for that last, I could see that being useful.

Comment: Now *that* we can agree on.

Comment: Tag only edits should have their own queue in my opinion. That would reduce the amount of edits in the main queue.

Comment: @Bugs This is an interesting proposal, I like this idea. Given the number of tag-only edits, I am pretty sure that it would mitigate this problem...

Comment: @Bugs I might suggest going one step further than this and grant immediate tag-only edits at a below-2k level. I'm not sure where a good line would be. Perhaps 1k. We already have UI for this, though for reasons not clear to me, you have to make it all the way to 10k to use it, instead of having the ability at 2k...

Comment: Also, the idea behind a different queue for tags is to act on them faster. Incorrect tags are always a problem on SO. With the wrong tag you get the wrong audience and often downvotes. By having it's own queue it _might_ help with moving questions to the right audience quicker.

Comment: It sounds like you're just requesting a relaxation of the edit queue limit. How will that achieve your stated goal of "encouraging in-depth edits"?

Comment: Didn't the queue become full *immediately* (i.e. day 1) after the top bar redesign and stay that way, having basically never filled up until that moment? I thought this was a direct consequence of removing the direct link to the suggested edit queue from the top bar, and that this was understood by everybody and had been pointed out on Meta on day 1 after the redesign went out. Maybe I'm confused, but I'm honestly kind of surprised to see any alternative explanations being floated here because I thought the explanation was both very obvious and already a matter of community consensus.

Comment: @MarkAmery I distinctly remember this too, IMO it would be rather disappointing if the whole edit policy of this site was changed to work around what was actually a UX issue.

Comment: @TylerH: I just want to have a guarantee that, no matter the time I spend on an edit, I will be able to save it immediately. This is not how the system works currently. Whether you modify everything or just a tag, it is still an "atomic" edit for SO. So obviously, people who are faster to save their superficial edits tend to eliminate slower contributors who make thorough edits...

Comment: @MarkAmery I tried to find the meta post to but I couldn't find the one I was thinking of. [I found this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343773/4975230), but let me know if there's a more relevant one that you know of.

Comment: @Badacadabra Ah, so you want an edit lock or a revision saving feature for edits. I can tell you at least that an edit lock has been requested several times by users and rejected each time; the staff doesn't think it's worth it.

Comment: @TylerH: Thanks for this information, it is good to know... I will modify my question to add more details, taking into account elements from this discussion. :)

Comment: @MarkAmery I have seen the Suggested Edit review queue full a couple times before the top bar redesign.

Comment: @Bugs, If we're going to separate the edit queue into a different queue for just tag edits, then perhaps we should separate out other types of easily reviewed edits. For instance, when only whitespace is changed (e.g. to re-indent code, or move code into code formatting). Alternately, inform reviewers that only specific things changed (e.g. tags, whitespace, etc.). Some edits are quite easy to review if we explicitly know exactly what changed, rather than having to look closely through a diff that is showing entire lines that have changed when it's just the whitespace within those lines.

Comment: @Makyen makes sense. Maybe a trivial edit queue and a substantial edit queue. Saw one post that got pounded on today because of code formatting and it only took someone to make the edit but needed to be reviewed. Would have been good if that was done quickly.

Comment: @jrh asking about it. [I think we can't blame hawthorne effect, how much /review participation dropped?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349119)

Comment: @Bugs tag only edits should not be suggested, period. If you have greater than 2000 reputation then fine, no one has to review it. If someone has to review your edits, you can find something better to do than waste our time with tag only edits.

Comment: @TinyGiant do you not feel a different queue would be beneficial? Maybe don't make them eligible unless you have 2k? There are a lot of tag edits that need to be done quickly or shouldn't be done at all. What are you thoughts? I'm not the only one who things so. It would be good to see why.

Comment: @Braiam good idea, I will follow both yours and Brad's topic. I'm interested to see how this turns out.

Comment: @Bugs if you have 2k, your edits edits don't need to be reviewed. I do not think that making a separate queue to justify suggested edits which the community has repeatedly established should not be suggested. The simple fix is for said users to address _all_ of the issues with a post, not just the tags. I have not ever seen a post that could not be improved in some way. The tags will never be the _only_ thing that can be improved.

Comment: @TinyGiant whilst I agree with you there is the simple matter that substantial edits aren't made and SO can't enforce that because posts may actually not need to have a substantial edit. Sometimes all it needs is a tag change and the previous edit _may_ may not have addressed it. So if 2 people with less than 2k make an edit, the first one addressing the grammar the second the tag then it's sat in the long queue twice. That is a problem and something which you have to assume will happen with how much traffic passes through the site. It would also help with burn requests on tags.

Comment: @Bugs The problem in need of solving is people making bad edit suggestions. _Lowering our standards_ is not a good way to solve that problem. As for burn requests, _no one_ should be submitting tag only edits for those. If the only thing left for a question is to remove a tag, **leave it alone**. Once all other questions have been taken care of, a community manager can remove the tag from all questions without bumping anything.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yeah OK makes sense re burn request. There is a problem with bad edits being suggested clogging up the queue. That's going to be difficult to solve. I do believe a tag only queue however would be beneficial if not only to get to the right audience quicker or as you say make it so only 2K can make those changes. If 2K required it would be worth allowing the edit of tags _even_ if there is a pending suggested edit, rather than having to wait. An option may be to create a chat room for the queue and have dedicated members handle the requests a bit quicker.

Comment: @Bugs If we create a queue where the sole intention is to reject every suggestion, we might as well implement an automated ban on those suggestions. If we implement an automated ban on tag only edits, users will add HTML comments or other such filler nonsense to the post to submit their edit. The _only_ solution is to better educate users on what is expected in an edit. This requires lots of research into how users currently navigate, what they see, what they read, what they don't see, what they don't read, etc. etc.

Comment: @TinyGiant educating the users would be a massive step in the right direction. I'll agree with that.

Comment: @Bugs it could be, but if done wrong [it could be ineffective or worse than what we already have](https://blog.codinghorror.com/treating-user-myopia/). Figuring out the best way to engage and educate users is a very long process with lots of research, guess work, and testing.

Comment: I think there should be a 100 rep. minimum to edit posts. I think newer users find editing posts a free +2 reputation, so they do extremely minor edits hoping to gain rep. However once you have about 100 rep, that +2 doesn't mean much, so they will edit post to improve them, rather than to gain reputation.

Comment: This feature request is starting to feel scope-creeped.  I suggest limiting the request to a single, cohesive set of changes.  Personally, I would split up the ideas for tag only edits, reputations requirements, and reputation rewards into separate requests.  They just seem too disjointed to be part of the same feature request.  Either that, or rename your feature request "Overhaul Suggested Edits" or something that communicates how large of an undertaking it would be.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Thanks for your suggestion. You are probably right, but the edit queue is a vast topic... Maybe we could keep this post as is (as a central discussion reference) and create peripheral topics with links from here to extend the debate in several directions. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that could work.  Right now, we just have a bunch of ideas floating around without specifics that potential SE devs could implement in a feature.  Even just removing the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag might be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I've only had access to the Edit Queue since 5/1 or 5/2 but I kind of like this idea:

> From my perspective, we need a real incentive (reputation or badge) to
>   increase the number of thorough edits and avoid reputation farming.
>   Reviewers could have the following evaluation options:
>
> - Good Edit: +2 reputation
> - Acceptable Edit: 0 reputation
> - Bad Edit: -1 reputation

I don't think we need new options for Good and Acceptable, the existing Approve and Approve & Edit options should already work here.

I also think that an Acceptable Edit should still give +1. I don't think an editor doing a lot of work but missing one lower case 'i' or a missing period should go unrewarded.

I go back and forth on whether bad edits should cost reputation. Maybe if "made the post worse" was it's own reject reason it could be tied to that.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this. `Approve`, `Improve Edit` and `Reject` buttons could correspond to `Good Edit`, `Acceptable Edit` and `Bad Edit`. But you are right: we cannot penalize someone who did a great job and just forgot a minor detail. An edit could be good and require some minor improvements. What I call an "acceptable edit" is the bare minimum to get `+2` reputation (like a correct tag-only edit). For edits that make the post worse (bad tags, useless indents or terrible grammar), a `-1` reputation seems logical. When you write a bad question or a bad answer on SO, you get downvotes...