# How did Stack Overflow decide its navbar height?

Tags: support, design

As I write this, Stack Overflow and SO Meta seem to have a navbar height of 60px, Stack Exchange Meta seems to have a navbar height of 40px, and other Stack Exchange sites (Law, Electrical Engineering) seem to have a navbar height of 34px.

I am in the process of creating a website that has a navbar, and I'm curious to know how Stack Overflow came to decide that 60px was the right number (i.e. what factors were considered when arriving at that decision).

---

It has been suggested that this question is opinion-based. At the moment, I don't believe it is. I am not asking users of Stack Overflow for their *guesses* at how the navbar height was decided, and I have been flagging all such comments on this question.

I suspect this is a question that can only be answered by a current or former engineer / PM / designer at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to be ale to set my own height and have it the same across all SE sites: [Top-navigation choices](https://stackapps.com/questions/7603/top-navigation-choices)

Comment: See [How Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/) and also the [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) Meta post

Comment: If you decide on a really tall navbar, don't forget to make it sticky as well. People love that!

Comment: They went to: https://www.random.org/ and typed in the values 30 & 60, then clicked "generate", hence the range of values you see.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was just based on icon size + sufficient padding space.

Comment: I noticed this some time ago. Different heights, I assumed its to fit the logo of each site :)

Comment: With a laptop of res 1366x768, I find 60px to be far too large and on top of that, it's sticky, and **then** the review banner/button section/"Question" or "Answer" header of reviews, I only have half a screen to review with. SE's use of vertical real estate truly is a bane for laptop users on low-res screens

Comment: @NickA There is an option to disable the "stickiness" of the navbar in the options section of your profile page.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ahah, that solves 1 problem, now I just need a way to configure it on a system basis instead of a user basis for when I'm at work

Comment: It looks too fat to me.

Comment: While the header element may be 60 pixels, the topbar itself is only 57 as 3 have been used for the nice dark border on top.

Comment: I don't know how the Stack Overflow engineers went about it, but I either play around with it in a mockup until I have something that works and looks good; that hasn't changed since the inception of the web. You know a logo and probably some input controls need to fit in there so you know or can measure the minimum height and can then move from there. More likely in this day and age however I would download Bootstrap or a similar CSS kickstart kit, set up a navbar using it and then do the least amount of CSS overrides as possible to suit my needs.

Comment: @becko that's what happens with too many hamburger menus.