# Salvage vertical screen space

Tags: feature-request, design

While work is ongoing to [remodel the top-bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653), I want to give general feedback on the usage of vertical space. Many developer screens are getting flatter, in particular laptops. Vertical space becomes more precious, stop wasting it.

### Tags and comments

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319924/what-is-process-and-thread?noredirect=1&lq=1):

[image: Sample question]

The question and answer are short enough to fit on one screen, yet the answer disappears below the fold. And the answer is what people will want to read most 99% of the time.

- The tags waste space, in particular once a question has had it's share of views and a chance to improve tags. They can go to the right column after a while (e.g. 1K views) to save vertical space.
- The comments waste space. Those are discussions from 2010, why would they, 7 years later, still be more important than the answer?
- The actions can be iconified, and go to some column (left, right or new). They cannot be more important than the actual answer.
- User boxes can be reduced to 2 rows of text / icon height.

I strongly urge to consider that questions in different phases of their lifetime deserve different ways to be displayed based on the most likely intentions of viewers. By all means encourage reviewing and changing for fresh questions, but prioritize the actual answers for matured questions.

### Reviews / Triage

[image: Sample review]

- The question starts is on the middle of the page with the title, it should start on top, at the height of 'Review | Triage'. Everything between the top-bar and the question title can go away, to one side or the other.
  Any hint for new reviewers should be hideable once reviewers got comfortable with the process.
- Given reviews do not respect my ignored tags, it would be quite helpful to see the question tags next to the title so that I can manually quickly decide if a question should not be judged by me. Even knowing that some of them I could still reasonably review.

### Search

Next the Search function with `intags:mine`, one of the more useful search filters that maddeningly is not even mentioned in the 'Advanced Search Tips', only in the Search help page (And why is there no simple textfield autocomplete suggestion for those filters anyway?). Since filters are so important for Answerers to block out stuff they cannot answer anyway, it is encouraged to have many tags. What does `intags:mine` do:

[image: intags mine]

Why is this? I want to see questions, not my tags.

### Other comments

If there is just one Answer, the space above the answer saying: "1 Answer, Active Oldest Votes' is waste. Generally consider visualizing the number of answers on the side rather than stealing vertical space between the question and the answer.

Comment: I think consistency is just as/more important here. Your brain gets trained where to look for things pretty quickly, if that kept changing depending on the age or whatever of the question, it could be quite jarring. Some of your points are good, but this movement towards trying to fit everything perfectly on the smallest possible screen is counter-intuitive IMO. When exactly did the scroll bar become such a pariah?

Comment: I am not trying to squeeze everything onto any page, just to move things with lower priority out of the way to get the 2 most important contents (question and 1st answer) above the fold of laptop screens, which are not 'the smallest possible screens' in any reasonable way to look at stackoverflow.

Comment: Meh, not worth the UX studies that would have to take place to ascertain the validity of such changes, IMO.

Comment: @Clive, you honestly believe that every single last one of these suggestions needs a UX study for its validity to be ascertained?

Comment: No, but then I didn't say that @xs0. When you look at them as a whole I think it'd warrant a bit of investigation before implementing, sure

Comment: While I agree that SE uses an excessive amount of vertical (white) space and I'm strongly disposed to agree with a topic called "Salvage vertical screen space", I disagree with many of your suggestions for question pages. I also agree with @Clive that consistency in presentation is important. The look of the page should not change radically based on the age of the question.

Comment: The fact that you've lumped your suggestions for multiple different pages together into one omnibus request made me have to work at not just dismissing everything after your suggestions for question pages. If you really want something to move forward, break this into separate FRs, *at least* by page type & create some mock-ups so people know what you're talking about.

Comment: For individual pages, I could make individual FRs, but site design is not done page-by-page, there needs to be some consistent design philosophy, and first I like to know if people agree that the current design philosophy does not care enough about vertical space.

Comment: @xs0 ugh... yeah, assertions like these should be studied, challenged, cited and proven, thank you very much. Just because a few people on the internets say that "screens are getting flatter" and "comments are useless" does not mean there is any consensus on it. What, are y'all market specialists or something? I myself am under the impression that most professional developers I know are getting bigger and bigger screens, not the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

I can get rid of several things that bug me with this Stylish config (based on [undistractify-stackoverflow](https://userstyles.org/styles/110637/undistractify-stackoverflow)):

```
/* hide distractors and space-wasters */
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

    /* discard by css class */

  .module.community-bulletin,   /* hot blogs. Distraction */
  .clc-jobs-multi,
  .bounty-notification,   /* bounties too expensive anyway. Wastes a lot of space */
  .bottom-share-links,    /* share question via Twitter? no thank you */
  .bottom-notice,         /* boring message telling me to look for other answers, distracts */
  .question-stats,  /* stats like views. Distraction */
  .search-header,
  .displaying-results--tagged, /* remove looong list of my tags when using "intags:mine" */

  /* discard by tag id= */

  #feed-link, /* wastes space to advertise feeds */
  #hot-network-questions,  /* other stackexchange site activity */
  #chat-feature,   /* chat activity */
  #newsletter-ad,  /* newsletter */
  #nav-users,  /* top navigation to all users, not needed */
  #nav-tags,   /* top navigation to all tags, not needed */
  #nav-jobs,   /* top navigation to all jobs, not needed */
  #hireme,     /* job advertisements */
  #clc-tsb,
  #answers-header,   /* number of answers and tabs, never useful. wastes space. */
  #ignored-footer,   /* Info message after search results. distraction */
  #related-tags,     /* related tags. Distraction */
  #footer-sites
  {
    display:none !important;
  }

/* dotted line above answers because header got removed */
#answers {
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Of course it hides things that Stackoverflow designers want to be displayed to me, I don't know what's the policy for promoting hacks to hide that. Also tried Greasemonkey scripts, but it seems that's not reliable for content added dynamically to sidebars, and also more complex than Stylish.

For several links I'd prefer to move them instead of hiding them, but I feel maintaining such a script would be much more effort.

I also got around to squeeze tags, links and userInfo side-by-side, to reduce vertical  space wastage.
For that, I removed the information about the last modification to a question. That information is almost never useful to me.

The result is not particularly pretty, but shows that the space can be sueezed. If Stackoverflow was a bot more consistently coded (not mixing div styling and html tables), better results could be achieved with Stylish.

```
/* Save space by combining tag / sharelink / userinfo lines */

.fw {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.vt {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-left: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
}

.post-taglist {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

.post-menu {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

/* hides last edit */
.postcell * .post-signature:not(.owner) {
    display: None;
}
```

Here is a side-by-side comparison:

[image]

Left is with my changes, right without. Main thing to notice is that white "Sahara" of zero-useful-information between question and answer on the right is missing on the left.

Of course this is not a complete design suggestion, only what I could achieve with a little css hacking.

Still looking for ways to reduce vertical space wastage by old comments and in the reviews page, not sure if Stylish is powerful enough to do something smart.